# Javascript: setting up a chain of prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

In Javascript, every object has a prototype. Any prototype is an object, therefore any prototype has a prototype.

This is me:

```
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype = {
    walk: function () {
        alert(this.name  + ' is walking');
    }
}

var walter = new Person('Walter');
```

I can walk:

```
walter.walk() // => "Walter is walking"
```

I wonder if people can fly? Programmers are gods, I'll just make people able to fly:

```
var WingedAnimal = function () {
    this.hasWings = true;
}

WingedAnimal.prototype = {
    fly: function () {
        alert(this.name + ' is flying')
    }
}

var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype =  {
    walk: function () {
        alert(this.name  + ' is walking');
    },
    prototype: new WingedAnimal()
}

var walter = new Person('Walter');

walter.walk() // => 'Walter is walking'

walter.fly();
```

**TypeError: walter.fly() is not a function**

OK then:

```
Person.prototype =  {
    walk: function () {
        alert(this.name  + ' is walking');
    }
}

Person.prototype.prototype = new WingedAnimal();

var walter = new Person('Walter');

walter.walk() // => 'Walter is walking'

walter.fly();
```

**TypeError: walter.fly() is not a function**

Is there really no way to do this? I mean, having a chain of prototypes rather than mixing multiple objects into a single prototype?

Not that I dislike mixing things together, but still...

---

To clarify my question:

At the moment I have already solved this problem with a function that I usually call *mix* and put in a namespace usually called *CORE*. The function copies the members of all the objects it's passed into the first object. My code usually looks like this:

```
var Constructor = function () {
    // stuff
}

CORE.mix(Constructor.prototype, SomeInterface, AnotherInterface, {
    //stuff that goes only into objects made with Constructor
});
```

Everything in SomeInterface, AnotherInterface and the object literal ends up into Constructor.prototype, precedence right to left. This is not, however, how I think Javascript should work. I should have, I think, a chain of prototypes, not just one prototype with a ton of stuff mixed into it.

When I call someObject.method, *method* should be searched into someObject; if it isn't there it should be searched into someObject.prototype; then in someObject.prototype.prototype; and so on until a prototype has an undefined prototype, then it should fail. This is how I understand it from [this great explanation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html). Am I wrong? Is **one** prototype for each object really all we can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Person.prototype= {
    walk: function () {
            alert(this.name  + ' is walking');
    },
    prototype: new WingedAnimal()
}
```

That doesn't work: the `prototype` property lives on the constructor function, not on the prototype object:

```
Person.prototype= new WingedAnimal();
Person.prototype.walk= function() {
    alert(this.name  + ' is walking');
};
```

However this is also flawed in that it's trying to base a class on an instance; this works for WingedAnimal because its constructor does nothing much, but it's a bad pattern (promulgated by many bad JS tutorials) that'll confuse any more complicated task.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript) for an overview of prototyping in JavaScript.

Comment: That clarified some things, thanks. Would you say that mixing everything into the same prototype is a better approach?

Comment: Well, whatever. You did answer, I'll sort the rest out myself

Comment: One prototype for WingedAnimal and Person? I'm hoping that's only an example case and any real case would have to be judged on its own merits. Personally I prefer relatively shallow prototype trees to Java-style deep inheritance, but I don't know that I'd make a Person a WingedAnimal. (!)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding the prototype property. While all objects do have an internal reference to their prototype, there's no way to get or set this directly in every browser. The `prototype` property is only useful when assigned to constructor functions.

```
Person.prototype = new WingedAnimal();

Person.prototype.walk = function () {
    alert(this.name  + ' is walking');
};

var walter = new Person('Walter');

walter.walk() // => 'Walter is walking'

walter.fly();
```