# Javascript Prototype Quirk - Can Anyone Explain This?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

My expectation from the following code would be that if I checked `a.name`, it would search the prototype and return it as it was declared. Can anyone pinpoint what it is that is preventing JS from acknowledging my prototype?

```
var obj = function(parent){
    return {
        prototype: parent
    }
};

var me = { name: 'keith' };

var a = new obj(me)
// => undefined

a.name
// => undefined

a.prototype.name
// => "keith"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property named "prototype" is just a property, it does not point to the object from which the object inherits. Use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf) or the [non-standard `__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) to get that.

So what your function `obj(me)` returns is just an object with a property "prototype" which points to an object with a property "name" which points to the string `keith`. As your function returns an object, it makes no difference whether it is called with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) or not.

For inheritance, the "prototype" property of the constructor function [object] is of concern. Every object created by this constructor (which does not return an object) with the `new` keyword inherits from the object to which the "prototype" property of the *constructor* points. So you could do this:

```
var Constructor = function() {
    console.log(this); // logs the currently created object
    // return nothing
}
Constructor.prototype = { name: 'keith' };

var a = new Constructor(); // logs an empty object
Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === Constructor.prototype; // true
a.name; // "keith" - inherited
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function you are not touching the function prototype. You are just returning a new object with property "prototype" with parent as a value. Therefore you can only access it through that property.

It seems that you are trying to implement inheritance, here's a good read about that: [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) and [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html)

Comment: Hey, you're right, I am trying for inheritance here. Thanks for those articles. I've read both thoroughly but I just think it's ugly to have to use a function that returns your object without using "new" in its creation. It's just a little unreadable in my opinion. Was hoping to find a way to make using "new" a possibility

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're overwriting the `prototype` property in a similar way to how you can overwrite the `undefined` "value".

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are returning a property named `prototype` with the value parent, which is an object, so you are returning the pair `prototype = {name = 'keith'}` and when you call new obj, you are adding to the prototype of `a` a new property named `prototype`.

You just need a bit change, I need this is what you are trying to do. This will work, just be carefull with overload properties.

```
var obj = function(parent){
   for(var propt in parent){
      this[propt] = parent[propt];
   }
}

var me = { name: 'keith' };
var a = new obj(me);
console.log(a);
// => Object { name="keith"}
console.log(a.name);
// => "keith"
```

Edit: If you are looking for inheritance using prototype, you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064731/good-example-of-javascripts-prototype-based-inheritance) or try [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), a new javascript typed and OO library

Comment: This is really just cloning properties from one object to another, whereas I'd ultimately like to be able to use "prototype" as one would use "super" in a classical language. This would work, but it isn't quite inheritance :-)

Comment: you didn't mention the inheritance. You are refering to the `super` keyword in `java` right?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have overwritten the real prototype with a fake one.

Comment: he just added a new property to `obj.prototype` named prototype

Comment: I think Rod is actually correct, it looks like somehow I abolished the internal link to "prototype" and replaced it with a property that JavaScript doesn't implement the prototype functionality on. I think it may be that the new keyword is initializing the object first, and *then* overwriting prototype with a new value, which is no longer in the scope chain