# Can anyone come up with a good prototype example in JS that helps me understand what prototypes are?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm reading about prototypes, but I can't seem to understand what they do and what the point of having them is. Can anyone create a simple example (ex. collegeStudent object) that will help me understand the basic concepts of prototypes? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064731/good-example-of-javascripts-prototype-based-inheritance

Comment: Please see my answer. I've done my best to make it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you create a function called `person`:

```
function person(name, age, gender) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
}
```

Now let's say you've created some new persons:

```
var fred = new person("fred", 35, "male");
var mary = new person("mary", 24, "female");
var joe = new person("joe", 46, "male");
```

`person` currently has three properties, `name,age, gender`.

Using prototype you can add a new property to the object AND to all previously instantiated objects.

`person.prototype.hairColor = null;` <-- If you set this to "brown" all previously instantiated objects will have the value "brown". So `fred.hairColor` would be brown.

**The great thing about this is that you can set all previously instantiated and future objects a default value without having to manually set the property on all of those objects.**