# ES6+ instance property instantiated outside of constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-next

Using ES6+ syntax in React/React-Native, the variable `foo`, when defined **outside of the constructor** is somehow transformed into an instance variable when called with `this.`. Is my assertion true? Why does it even work, when not instantiated in the constructor? Here a corresponding React Native code snippet:

```
class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  foo = "bar";

  render() {
    return ( <View>{ this.foo }</View> );
  }
}
```

---

[This discussion about ES7 property initializers](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es7-property-initializers) shows how the `state` variable is prominently used in this way in React/React Native.

So far related Stack Overflow discussions I read through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545495/es6-class-instance-properties) could not answer this question for me..

Comment: "*Why does it even work, when not instantiated in the constructor?*" - because class fields are a horrible idea

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37788342/465053).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assertion is true.

The problem is that it's currently just in the `stage-1`, so it's not clear when and if ever it becomes the standard.

References:

- https://github.com/tc39/ecma262
- https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties
- https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties#part-1-class-instance-fields

Comment: I see. Thanks for the links! I wasn't aware about the entire ECMAScript  development process with different stages and such.