# Is it possible to use arrow functions in classes with ES6?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

My question is very simple. If I have a class in ES6 is it possible to use an arrow function within it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SearchForm extends Component {

  state = {
    searchText: ''
  }

  onSearchChange = e => {
    this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSearch(this.query.value);
    e.currentTarget.reset();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
        <label className="is-hidden" htmlFor="search">Search</label>
        <input type="search"
               onChange={this.onSearchChange}
               name="search"
               ref={(input) => this.query = input}
               placeholder="Search..." />
        <button type="submit" id="submit" className="search-button">
          <i className="material-icons icn-search">search</i>
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The reason I ask is that I get an error in my console, even when using Babel. It seems like there's a lot of resources on the internet stating you can do this (most of which are about developing with React).

Is this something that Babel should do, and will eventually become natively supported?

The error I get is an unexpected = sign, just before the parens.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, the reason I wish to do this is to make use of the `this` keyword in context of the class. If I use a regular function - to my understanding - I would have to bind `this` to the function. I'm trying to look for a nicer way of doing that.

Comment: No, it's not the way things work. The right way is the constructor() {} provided with sample.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to? What would be the benefit?

Comment: Developing with React and wanting to make use of the this keyword without explicitly binding it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-es6-arrow-in-class-methods - possibly duplicate question

Comment: Arrow 'methods' have been proposed (currently stage 1 draft) for inclusion into the standard here: https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/

Comment: Do NOT use an arrow function for a method that you want `this` to point to the object instance.  The arrow function definition will use a lexical `this`, NOT the object `this`.  That's just a misuse of an arrow function.  It's not just a syntax shortcut - it changes the value of `this` in a way which is inappropriate for nearly all method definitions.  An arrow function is simply the WRONG tool for the job when declaring methods.

Comment: Regarding a 'nicer' way, see this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/43601993/3731501 . The fact that arrows look a bit neater than `bind` doesn't make them nicer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll need to add the `transform-class-properties` babel plugin, which allows you to have auto-bound class methods like you are attempting.

Unlike what others have just suggested, there IS value in doing this. Namely, your class function automatically has the class `this` bound to it, without having to manually bind it in your constructor.

Without the `transform-class-properties` plugin, you could do:

```
export default class SearchForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this)
  }

  doSomething () {
    console.log(this) // <-- 'this' is the class instance
  }
}
```

With the plugin:

```
export default class SearchForm extends Component {

  doSomething = () => {
    console.log(this) // <-- 'this' is the class instance, no binding necessary
  }
}
```

Heres and article that explains it (among other thing) fairly well and 
consisely: https://medium.com/@joshblack/writing-a-react-component-in-es2015-a0b27e1ed50a

Comment: This is the exact conclusion I've came to before you answered, reason I wanted this to refer to the class is so I can use 'this.setState' and refer to the class itself.

Comment: Exactly. This is a fairly typical React component pattern

Comment: Slightly off topic, but in the same class there is an object defined, i.e. within the class there is state = { ... }. Is this another experimental feature, and how does it differ to using this.state = { ... } within the constructor?

Comment: Not sure. Could you update your code example to show it?

Comment: Have updated, looks like it's instead of using the constructor but I'm not sure?

Comment: Ah, that actually never occurred to me, but (as long as you're using the transform plugin I mentioned) it should be the same thing. Its just a cleaner way of defining a class property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788342/is-it-better-to-define-state-in-constructor-or-using-property-initializers

Comment: What's the point of declaring a method as an arrow function and then overriding that with an auto-bound method?  Doesn't make any sense.  Basically arrow functions make no sense for methods where you want `this` to be the object instance.  People are trying to use arrow functions because they love the syntax shortcut without paying any attention to what they are good for and not good for.  That's what people need to actually learn.

Comment: @jfriend00 When using React I want to use this to modify the class itself, I.e access this.state and be able to access the components state. I'm not sure what you said about the object instance applies here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use arrow functions inside ES6 classes. I noticed that you are not calling `super` inside your constructor you have to do that if you are extending and overriding the constructor.

Other than that your code compiles correctly to ES5, checkout this [link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=class%20SearchForm%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doSomething%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) to the online Babel transpiler that contains your sample code.

Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-es6-arrow-in-class-methods) similar to yours.

Comment: Even when calling super() I still get the syntax error, it only works when using the 'transform-class-properties' plugin for Babel, not sure why the Babel online transpiler would work unless it already takes that into consideration and uses the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Your code should work, you need to check you Babel setup, there must be something wrong with how it's configured.

In your example, `doSomething` is actually a property of the class; the type of the property is a function. Here's an example that additionally shows a method, as well as a use of the `this` keyword:

```
class SearchForm {

  doSomething = () => {
    console.log('I am a property')
  }

  doSomethingElse() {
    console.log('I am a method')
  }

  doBoth() {
    this.doSomething();
    this.doSomethingElse()
  }
}

const form = new SearchForm();
form.doBoth();
```

You can check it out live [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=class%20SearchForm%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20doSomething%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('I%20am%20a%20property')%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20doSomethingElse()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('I%20am%20a%20method')%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20doBoth()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSomething()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSomethingElse()%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20form%20%3D%20new%20SearchForm()%3B%0Aform.doBoth()).

Comment: This answer does not address anything about using arrow functions to define the methods which is what the question appears to be about.