# Difference between funcName() {} and funcName = () => {} in ES6

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've been learning about React Native recently and I needed to access a custom component's properties after the component is, e.g. touched. I defined the following component:

```
export class OperationBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  startOperation() {
    Alert.alert("starting operation " + this.props.operation);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.startOperation}>
          <Text>{this.props.operation}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

    );
  }
}
```

The app crashes when the component is touched saying that `undefined is not an object when evaluating this.props.operation`. However if I define the function `startOperation()` like this: `startOperation = () => { ... }`, I get the expected behaviour.

Now, I thought I understood how these arrow functions worked. Coming from a Swift background, I thought they were just like closures, but surely I'm missing something? Why does the first way not work but the second does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer:
In [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

`funcName() {}` creates **"Class Methods"**  but  `funcName = () => {}` don't.

It's about all [ECMASCRIPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) 2015 **syntax** standards.

However, you can overcome that ;)

[Is it possible to use arrow functions in classes with ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080928/is-it-possible-to-use-arrow-functions-in-classes-with-es6)

Answer (score 0):

Because function is not binded to the class if defined as:

```
someFunction() { }
```

And is binded if defined as:

```
someFunction = () => { }
```

Another possibility is to explicitly bind it in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
}
```

Difference is that `startOperation` function is passed as callback, and executed in different environment (outside the initial class), so `this` is referring to different object.