# about using ES6 class in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6

I have some question that is about using ES6 class in react.

The question is as follows.

About creating component in react,

I am using this way.

```
class A extends Component{
    constructor(){
        this.state = {
            'blah' : 123
        }
    }
}
```

but i saw other way.

```
class A extends Component{
    state = {
        'blah' : 123
    }    
}
```

question 1)

what is difference between first way and second way?

question 2)

In the environment I built,

The second method generates an error.

how to use second way? (directly defining state)

Comment: They are equivalent. The second one is currently a proposal for extending the language with that syntax. You need to configure your build tool to understand this syntax.

Comment: check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788410/7750289

Answer (score 1):

Question1 : There is no difference in first and second way both can be used to initializing state.

Question2 : You can use second approach in the react version 16 or above. It is not supported in old version. For old version you still need to use approach 1 that is constructor approach.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The syntax is completely independent of the React version you are using. It has nothing to do with React.

Comment: @FelixKling OK, So what create the difference then Babel or anything else ?

Comment: Yes, this Babel plugin is responsible for performing the transformation: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: Thank you so much!!
The answers helped me