# React - constructor function

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I'm trying to learn react.

The documentation for react says to pass constructor arguments as follows.

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }


  render() {
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e) says the reason to reference super in that function is you might need to have props in super() if you want to access this.props in the constructor.

But - if you don't need to do that, and you just need to initialise state, do you still need the super() line?

I have seen a lot of tutorials that define it as follows:

```
class Basic extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedValue: null,
    createdAt: null
  };
```

I can't find a reference to why this is acceptable.  Do you need super, even if you don't need props in the constructor?

Comment: You never use `props` (this.props) then you dont need write `super(props)`. Its unnecessary

Comment: ok but do you need super()?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the constructor(props) and whether it's mandatory in a class that has a state

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - where is the better question that has already got an answer. It would be helpful if you could link to it in your flag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788342/is-it-better-to-define-state-in-constructor-or-using-property-initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet uses [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  this.state = {...};
  ...
}
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...};
  }
}
```

In case a class doesn't need explicit constructor, `constructor` can be omitted. In case it needed explicit constructor, it should contain `super(props)` because it's required to properly inherit from `React.Component`.

Comment: Hi - I don't know which bit of the document you linked is relevant. The first example in that document still uses constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = this.clicked.bind(this);
    this.x = 0;
  }

Comment: Read it further. It explains that first example you mentioned is desugared ES2015, and second example is sugared ES.next and replaces `this.x =` with `x =`.

Comment: Are you referring to this paragraph: In the above example, you can see a field declared with the syntax x = 0. You can also declare a field without an initializer as x. By declaring fields up-front, class definitions become more self-documenting; instances go through fewer state transitions, as declared fields are always present. ? If so, where do I find a translation guide to figure out the jargon?

Comment: 'Fields' are defined in the proposal itself, https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/ . The rest seem to be regular programming terminology. As for me, the difference between snippets speaks for itself. `this.x =` becomes `x =`.

Comment: No idea what you mean. Thanks for trying to help but you're too smart for me to keep up with.

Comment: Are you saying the react documentation is deprecated by developments in regular programming?

Comment: React documentation was written by different contributors at different time.  I cannot say why `constructor(props) {
    super(props);` is there, it could be added to give a better impression what's going on if a reader isn't familiar with class fields (which are supported in React toolchain but aren't standardized and thus aren't valid JS yet). Any way, `constructor` can be skipped in almost all components, including this one, this also allows to avoid very common mistake, `constructor(props) {
    super()` (no props argument for super).

Comment: Thanks. I found this. It helps. I didn't realise the react documents weren't best practice guidelines.  https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

Answer (score 0):

This requirement doesn't related with React it's related with new ECMAScript 2015 Classes.

Look the Inheritance syntax section at this mozilla article;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance#Inheritance_with_class_syntax

When you create a new react component you need inherit from React.Component class. So if you need to define a constructor for your class you need call super otherwise don't need it.

Comment: Okay -so are you saying that if it's not a subclass, then there is no need to use constructor?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out when I need to define a constructor.

Comment: Absolutely yes. Look at the above article.

Comment: If you need some initialization for you class like your state. You define a constructor. So if you defined a constructor you need call super because of you inherit from React.Component class. That's a requirement for ES2015 classes.

Comment: What are you saying 'yes' to? I've read that document about 5 times today. Are you saying that if I don't need a subclass on my private class, then no need for a constructor, or are you saying that because everything inherits from react, that it's always needed?

Comment: It doesn't related to whether you need a constructor or don't. I say if you inherit from a parent class and if you need a constructor you have to call super. When you write a class and you don't inherit from any parent class so you don't need calling super you can define a constructor anyway.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Thanks for trying to help, but I haven't communicated my question to you clearly, obviously.

Comment: Sure not problem. Sorry I was write careless. I've edited again my comment.

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean. I'm trying to figure out when I need a constructor.

Comment: If question is "when do I need a constructor?" it's about your business.

Comment: No idea what you mean. I don't think we are communicating clearly. Thank you for trying to help. I'll try to figure out what's happening in the constructor and update this post with an answer when I come up with an understanding. I appreciate your effort to try to help.