# Can't export constant in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import, export, constants

Can someone help me please

I have 2 files main.ts and hi.ts

hi.ts:

```
export const hello = "dd";
```

main.ts:

```
import { hello } from "./hi";
...
class A {
    public sayHello() {
        console.log("hello=" + hello);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have exception:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined(…)

How can I see this const variable from class A? Is it possible?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647215/declaring-static-constants-in-es6-classes

Comment: I do 
export const hello = "dd"; 
like in your link but it doesn't work

Comment: In Node.js or in a browser?

Comment: in a browser (chrome and firefox the same)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

My answer refers to TypeScript 2+.

```
// 1.ts
export const AdminUser = { ... }

// index.ts
import * as users from './docs/users/admin';
var adminUser = users.AdminUser;
```

The only difference between your code and mine is the `*` operator in the import statement.

Answer (score 1):

// hi.ts

```
export const hello: string = "dd";
```

You must also specify the type of the const.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).