# Reading Const from ts file: 404 file not found in angular2

Tags: angular, constants

I am new to angular2. I am facing an issue while trying to read const from external **.ts** file using

```
import {apis} from '../constants/apis';
```

where **constants/apis.ts** file is :

```
 export const apis = {
     lookUp: "api/getLookup.php"
 }
```

its giving an error 
 ***GET http://localhost:3000/constants/apis 404 (Not Found)***

How can i fix this issue?

I am using **VSCode**, the path `'../constants/apis'` is suggested by **VSCode** and it is correct.

Comment: What happens if you replace `const` with `class`?

Answer (score 0):

try to write this:

```
import * as api from '../constants/a';
let route = api.lookUp;
```

you can find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385933/cant-export-constant-in-typescript)