# Attempting to compile this code simply wont work. Getting a parsing error from react.js and vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code:

```
  const shape = {
  id: Prop.Type.string.isRequired,
  message: Prop.Type.node.isRequired,
  link: Prop.Type.string,
  options:Prop.Type.arrayOf(
    Prop.Type.shape(NestedDropdown.shape)
  )
};
```

And a screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY9NV.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "const" when defining a field inside a class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Fields are defined like this:

```
class Rectangle {
  height = 0;
  width;
}
```

There is some discussion of how to create constants in this thread: [Declaring static constants in ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647215/declaring-static-constants-in-es6-classes)