# Declare a class property outside of a class method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, class-fields

See how x and y are declared in constructor:

```
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  toString() {
    return '(' + this.x + ', ' + this.y + ')';
  }
}
```

is there an way to declare properties outside of functions for instance:

```
class Point {
  // Declare static class property here
  // a: 22
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  toString() {
    return '(' + this.x + ', ' + this.y + ')';
  }
}
```

So I want to assign a to 22 but I am unsure if i can do it outside the constructor but still inside the class..

Comment: I think you could use `static get x(){ return 5; }`, which ends up doing the same thing, just rather wordy.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Initializing properties directly on a class in ES6 is [not possible](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes), only methods can currently be declared in this way. Same rules stand in ES7 as well.

However, it is a proposed feature that might come after ES7 (currently in stage 3). Here is the [official proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

Additionally, the syntax the proposal is suggesting is [slightly different](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#field-declarations) (`=` instead of `:`):

```
class Point {
  // Declare class property
  a = 22
  // Declare class static property
  static b = 33
}
```

If you are using Babel, you can use the stage 3 settings to enable this feature.

[Here's a Babel REPL example](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&code=class%20Point%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Declare%20class%20property%0A%20%20a%20%3D%2022%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Declare%20class%20static%20property%0A%20%20static%20b%20%3D%2033%0A%7D)

---

The other way to do this in ES6, other than in the constructor, is to do it after the class definition:

```
class Point {
  // ...
}

// Declare class property
Point.prototype.a = 22;

// Declare class static property
Point.b = 33;
```

Here's a [good SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives?rq=1) diving into this topic some more

---

*Note*:

As **Bergi** mentioned in the comments, the suggested syntax:

```
class Point {
  // Declare class property
  a = 22
}
```

is just syntactic sugar to provide a shortcut for this code:

```
class Point {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 22;
  }
}
```

Where both of those statements assign a property to an *instance*.

However, this isn't exactly the same as assigning to the prototype:

```
class Point {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 22;  // this becomes a property directly on the instance
  }
}

Point.prototype.b = 33; // this becomes a property on the prototype
```

Both would still be available via an instance:

```
var point = new Point();
p.a // 22
p.b // 33
```

But getting `b` would require going up the prototype chain while `a` is available directly on the object.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just use `static get x(){}` as well? Just wondering. In effect its the same thing right?

Comment: Well, it's not really the same effect but can be similar. You can use `get` to obtain a constant value or another value declared in the constructor which is not the same as declaring a value that can be directly get/set

Comment: Hmmm true. Ah well, thank god its only syntactic sugar and we can always rely on js's great object legacy :)

Comment: Gotta love them prototypes :)

Comment: You might want to add that `a = 22` is not the same as assigning to the prototype, instead it is very confusing sugar for creating instance properties in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

@nem035 is right that it is in proposal stage.

However, @nem035's sugggetion is one way to achieve it as class instance member.

> // Declare static class property here

Seems you are looking to declare a static member. If yes, 
JavaScript way is

```
class Point {
  // ...
}
Point.a = '22';
```

The way you are actually expecting can be done in TypeScript

```
class Point {
     static a = 22;
}
```

The compiled output will be same as above example

```
Point.a = '22';
```