# this scope inside the class after the constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, this

```
class User{
    constructor(username,email){
        this.username= username,
        this.email = email,
        this.score = 0
    }
    a = [this.email]  // showing undefined 
    login(){
        console.log(`you have logged in ${this.username}`);
        return this;
    }
    logout(){
        console.log(`you have logout ${this.username}`);
        return this;
    }
    incScore() {
        this.score +=1;
        console.log(`The ${this.username} have scored ${this.score}`)
        return this;
    }


}

const userOne = new User('mdvenkatesh','mdv@gmail.com');
console.log(userOne)

// but check it here 


class User{
    constructor(username,email){
        this.username= username,
        this.email = email,
        this.score = 0
    }
    a = [this]  // showing the complete user data  
    login(){
        console.log(`you have logged in ${this.username}`);
        return this;
    }
    logout(){
        console.log(`you have logout ${this.username}`);
        return this;
    }
    incScore() {
        this.score +=1;
        console.log(`The ${this.username} have scored ${this.score}`)
        return this;
    }


}
```

After my class i declared a array a and intilized with the this keyword 
o/p

> ```
> a: Array(1)
> 0: User {a: Array(1), username: "mdvenkatesh", email: "mdv@gmail.com", score: 0}
> length: 1
> __proto__: Array(0)
> email: "mdv@gmail.com"
> score: 0
> ```
>
> username: "mdvenkatesh"

but when i tryed with user.name it is showing undefined the o/p is following

```
User {a: Array(1), username: "mdvenkatesh", email: "mdv@gmail.com", score: 0}
a: [undefined]
email: "mdv@gmail.com"
score: 0
username: "mdvenkatesh"
__proto__: Object
```

i cantunderstand why you may thing why schould even intilize a varable outside method i want to know how a is treated here i am thinking it is proprtey of the class (plese correct me if i am wrong )

2)why this.username is showing undefined when user is show the data plese help me to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `a = [ this.username ]`, `username` is a string and hence its passed via value.

When you do `a = [ this ]`, `this` being an object is passes via reference. So any changes made to `this` will be reflected in `a`.

---

> here i am thinking it is property of the class

Your assumption is correct. But properties are initialized during compile-time and are updated in constructor. This way is used to set default values/ static values.

If you wish to have a property that gets you value of a property, use `getter` function.

---

Following is the illustration of above points:

- I have created a `getter` function called `userName` that returns necessary value.
- I have also moved `this.scope = 0` outside constructor as this is a default value.

```js
class User {
  score = 0;
  constructor(username, email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
  }
  get userName() {
    return this.username;
  }
  login() {
    console.log(`you have logged in ${this.username}`);
    return this;
  }
  logout() {
    console.log(`you have logout ${this.username}`);
    return this;
  }
  incScore() {
    this.score += 1;
    console.log(`The ${this.username} have scored ${this.score}`)
    return this;
  }
}

const user = new User('foo', 'foo@bar.com');
console.log(user.userName)
user.incScore();
```

#### Renerences:

- [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change)
- [Declare a class property outside of a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269083/declare-a-class-property-outside-of-a-class-method)
- [Classes - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Thanks 
but a = [ this.username ] is alredy intilized to some username why it is showing undefined

Comment: @mdvenkateshnuhk Its initialized in constructor but `a` is being assigned value during class definition phase. Anything outside constructor is assumed to be a part of class and is processed during creating the class itself, including properties. But properties are overridden in constructor. This is the ideal flow/behavior. Hope it clarifies your query

Comment: thanks 
Very helpful and update these line your answer and plese link any documention which gives more information

Comment: Add this is a reference type

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [this]  // you declared this to var a then use a after a = [this] use like below
    login(){
        return console.log(`you have logged in ${a.username}`);
    }
and try user.username 
User {a: Array(1), username: "mdvenkatesh", email: "mdv@gmail.com", score: 0}
user.name not find
```

please check example in below link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes