# Angular Node | SocketIO | Event not emitted from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, socket.io

I had asked this question before but here's a simple code for the same.
Im sending the data to Node from angular via websocket but I don't get the emitted event:
I've followed 10+ tutorials and forums, newest from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66T2A2dvplY&t=317s

service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
    socket = io('ws://localhost:3000');    // adding 'http://localhost:3000' also doesnt work
    constructor() {}

    listen(eventName: string) {
        return new Observable( subscriber => {
            this.socket.on(eventName, data => {
                subscriber.next(data);
            });
        });
    }

    emit(eventName: string, data) {
        this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
    }
}
```

from component's ngOnInit(), this is called:

```
this._socketService.listen('test event').subscribe( data => {
      console.log("data from server: ", data);
});
```

server code of Node:

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = require('http').createServer(app);


const socketio = require('socket.io');
const io = socketio(server, 
  {
    serveClient: true,
    pingInterval: 60000,
    pingTimeout: 60000000,
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:4200",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      credentials: true
    }
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("A user connected ", socket.connected);             // works till here for every ping interval
  socket.emit('test event', 'here is some data');     // this is either not executed or doesn't work
});

server.listen(port);
```

`socket.connected` is always `true` in NODE server, but `false` in Angular

What Ive tried:

- CORS has been suppressed, I hope that's not the issue cuz nothing is seen like so
- changing `io.('connection' ...)` to `io.connect('connect'...)`
- init `this.socket = io(...)` in constructor
- There is no data exchange seen in Network or Network > WS tab in case I emit from Angular too
- This is my 3rd day with this problem, I'll highly appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried moving the assignment into the `constructor`? `constructor() { this.socket = io(...) }` [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269083/declare-a-class-property-outside-of-a-class-method)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger yes I did. same thing. also tries in Node server from ```io.('connection', ...)``` to ```io.('connect', ...)``` 
the connection status in Node server ```socket.connected``` is ```true``` but it is false from Angular

Answer (score 0):

your mixing protocols from client.

change

```
socket = io('ws://localhost:3000');
```

to

```
socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { withCredentials: true });
```

As mentioned in [introduction](https://socket.io/docs/v3/index.html) under chapter **What Socket.IO is not** that socket.io is not a pure WS lib.

Comment: OP states in the code that this doesn't work.

Comment: @DaveNewton ah, thanks. Missed that comment from phone.

Comment: @Lucho it didnt work. maybe something else, whenever I do ```console.log(this.socket.emit(eventName, data))``` I get this Socket object with sendBuffer array and ```connected: false, disconnected: true```

```
connected: false
disconnected: true
io: Manager {nsps: {…}, subs: Array(1), opts: {…}, _reconnection: true, _reconnectionAttempts: Infinity, …}
nsp: "/"
receiveBuffer: []
sendBuffer: Array(2)
0:
data: (2) ["test event", {…}]
options: {compress: true}
type: 2
1:
data: Array(2)
0: "test event"
1: {message: "hello server"}
length: 2
options: {compress: true}
type: 2
```