# Static propTypes not working under ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to add some rules for props:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = { name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired };

  render() {
    return(
    )
  }
}
```

But I got this an error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `name` was not specified in `App`.
```

I have this configuration for babel:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

What I did wrong?

**Upd.** Change code: use `static`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 class variable alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears the you aren't transpiling your code in a way that can recognize static class properties. 
If you are using babel this can be enabled by using the Class Property Transform : https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/.

In our code base we get this functionality with the Stage 1 preset, https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/

Of course you could always define your proptypes on the class:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    ...
  } 
}

App.propTypes = {
 data: PropTypes.object.isRequired...
}
```

^^ this doesn't require any special transpilation.

The in class static property is nice though so you can set it up like this

```
export default class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = { name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired };
  render() {...} 
}
```

rather than define the propTypes on `this` in the constructor.

Comment: I turned on this plugin `transform-class-properties`, but still continue to get this error

Comment: Changed to use `static` but got this error: `Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop name was not specified in App.`

Comment: So that is good -- you want your `App` to require the prop `name`, it is telling you that you forgot this required prop. Either supply the prop, eg <App name="Test Name"/>, or remove the isRquired from the propTypes validation.

Comment: I have run into issues with ReactRouter where although I thought I always supplied a prop, RR would render the component without the prop, so had to remove the `isRequired` designation.

Comment: Oh, I see, but what if I have `name` in object? `var a = { id: 1, name: 'name', description: 'description11' }` `App data={a} />`

Comment: Then you will want to do something like this
propTypes = {data: PropTypes.shape({id: PropTypes.number, name: PropTypes. string ...})
    Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: It appears to be a part of stage-2 at least now. Since that's what I'm using and it works.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm leaving this answer for the comments but Timothy's answer regarding Babel is better.*

---

In ES6, classes have methods, and that's it--not even properties, let alone static:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

ES2017 may support a different property mechanism:

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es7-property-initializers

This question is strongly related to [ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22528967/438992) and is ultimately probably a dupe.

Comment: so it should be something like this: `constructor(){ this.propTypes = { name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired }; }` ?

Comment: @Meldum I suppose, but that creates them for every instance, which seems like a waste.

Comment: ES2016 will not have static properties: http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/ecmascript-2016.html

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, I think :/ That's the smallest feature set release I've ever seen.

Comment: @DaveNewton those are just "new features", there is a lot (?) of fixes of what was brought with ES2015.

Answer (score 2):

This is ES7 class static property feature.

You can use it with `babel-presets-stage-1`. Here is the doc 
http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/ and 
http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

If you want to use all features of ES7, you just need install the `babel-preset-stage-0`.

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Because `stage-0` dependency is `stage-1`, `stage-1` dependency `stage-2` and so on. The `npm` will install all dependencies. So you can use all ES7's feature.

Comment: (Not ES2016 anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

**USING BABEL 7**

As of babel v7.1.0, to use static class properties as well as properties declared with the property initializer syntax, you need to install a plugin as below:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

Also, all babel's yearly presets were deprecated, so instead of using `es2015` simply install and use `@babel/preset-env` alongside `@babel/preset-react`. Your babel configuration should look as below:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],]
}
```

Read more about the plugin [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties).

With the above installations and configurations, you can rewrite your component as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = { name: PropTypes.string.isRequired };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Static Class Properties</div>
    );
  }
}
```

And voila it works!!

**NOTE**: `PropTypes` is not in `react` package anymore, you need to import it separately from `prop-types` package.