# Is there a way to exploit the performance advantages of using prototype methods in JavaScript factory functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, prototype, factory, factory-pattern

I'm looking for the best way to write object-oriented JavaScript (JS) code in a way that is similar to Java classes.

Factory functions (FFs) look like a very promising way of offering class-like functionality in JS and, so far, I've been building them like this:

```
function FF(constructorArg)
{
   var _privateName = constructorArg;

   var publicMessage = "Hello StackOverflow";

   function publicMethodGetName() {
      return _privateName;
   }

   return {
      publicMethodGetName: publicMethodGetName,
      publicMessage: publicMessage
   };
}
```

However, [I've recently discovered that, unlike prototype methods, this style of FF recreates each method for every FF instance and can thus disadvantage performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/js-why-use-prototype).

In the second answer in [this excellent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions), Eric Elliot says about FFs:

> If you store prototypes on the parent object, that can be a great way
>   to dynamically swap out functionality, and enable very flexible
>   polymorphism for your object instantiation.

I can't find any examples of this online. Could anyone explain to me how I can do this using my FF above?

If I know that many objects are going to be created from the same FF does this mean that I could switch that FF to using prototype methods?

Comment: Not if you need the prototype methods to access your private FF-scoped variables.

Comment: Have your factory function just do `return new SomeObj()` and use the prototype of `SomeObj`.   But, that conflicts with some of the other features you are using (like private instance data) in your implementation.  In general, you pick one or the other and live with the advantages/disadvantages of that choice.

Comment: @jfriend00 would you be kind enough to provide a basic, but fully fleshed-out, example of what you're talking about? I'm new to the concept of prototypical inheritance and find it difficult to understand without code examples. By the way, if you post as an answer, I'll very likely make it the accepted one.

Comment: @user5508297 - You really have to describe what your requirements are.  Your example shows private instance variables.  You don't get that by default from prototyped methods.  There are work-arounds, but they're a bit ugly.  So, what exactly is your requirement that steers you away from using regular prototyped methods as Javascript was designed for.  Or, using the ES6 class syntax (which is just sugar syntax over prototyped methods in the implementation).

Comment: I haven't provided an answer because I can't really tell what question you are asking because the requirements are not clear.

Comment: @jfriend00 At the moment, I don't have any strict requirements - I'm just a beginner exploring class-like structures in JavaScript. I would be very interested in learning about 2 things you mentioned: 1.) How to use prototyped methods in a FF with no private fields and 2.) What the 'ugly' work-around for using private fields with prototyped methods looks like.

Comment: Although not a 'requirement' of mine, I should tell you, @jfriend00, that I think FFs are very elegant and that's why I'm particularly interested in learning about them.

Comment: Factory functions emphasize the fact that Javascript **objects are just prototypes** and exactly no classes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm looking for the best way to write object-oriented JavaScript (JS)
>   code in a way that is similar to Java classes.

This is your first mistake.  Javascript is a very different language and you should not be trying to emulate some other language in Javascript.  I kind of did something similar when I came from C++ and it was a big mistake.  What you need to do instead is learn the strengths of Javascript and how best to solve problems the "Javascript way" when writing in Javascript.  I know it's a natural tendency to look to do things the way you already know in some other language, but that is a mistake.  So, instead of trying to do things the "Java way", ask what is the best way in Javascript to solve some specific problem.

For example, the lowest memory way to have methods on a large number of objects is by using Javascript's prototype.  You can use the prototype either with manual assignments to the prototype or with the newer ES6 `class` syntax.  Both create methods on a prototype object that is then efficiently shared among all instances.

For example, you can use a factory function with a typical prototype like this:

```
// constructor and factory function definition
function MyCntr(initialCnt) {
    if (!(this instanceof MyCntr)) {
        return new MyCntr(initialCnt);
    } else {
        // initialize properties
        this.cntr = initialCnt || 0;
    }
}

MyObject.prototype = {
    getCntr: function() {
        return this.cntr++;
    },
    resetCntr: function() {
        this.cntr = 0;
    }
};
```

Then, you can create an object with the traditional `new` operator either like this:

```
var m = new MyCntr(10);
console.log(m.getCntr());    // 10
```

Or, you can use it as a factory function:

```
var m = MyCntr(10);
console.log(m.getCntr());    // 10
```

---

Keep in mind that with ES6 (or a transpiler), you can use ES6 class syntax too:

```
class MyCntr {
    constructor(initialCnt) {
        if (!(this instanceof MyCntr)) {
            return new MyCntr(initialCnt);
        } else {
            // initialize properties
            this.cntr = initialCnt || 0;
        }
    }

    getCntr() {
        return this.cntr++;
    }

    resetCntr() {
        this.cntr = 0;
    } 
}

var m = new MyCntr(10);
console.log(m.getCntr());    // 10
```

Or, you can use it as a factory function:

```
var m = MyCntr(10);
console.log(m.getCntr());    // 10
```

Both of these syntaxes create the exact same object definition and prototype.

---

All that said, the memory consumption of not using the prototype is usually not a big deal unless you have both a lot of methods and a lot of objects and there are some significant advantages to not using the prototype.  One big one is that you can have truly private instance data in a closure created by your constructor.  Here's the same previous example implemented that way where the `cntr` instance variable is truly private.

```
// constructor and factory function definition
function MyCntr(initialCnt) {
    // truly private instance variable
    var cntr;

    if (!(this instanceof MyCntr)) {
        return new MyCntr(initialCnt);
    } else {
        // initialize properties
        cntr = initialCnt || 0;
    }

    this.getCntr = function() {
        return cntr++;
    }

    this.resetCntr = function() {
        cntr = 0;
    }
}
```

This does use more memory as there is both a lasting closure created by the constructor function (that contains the `cntr` variable) and there are new instances of each of the functions that make up the methods.  But, it's not a big difference in memory.  If you don't have zillions of cntr objects, the memory consumption difference is likely inconsequential.  Doug Crawford is one of the champions of such a Javascript coding style.  You can see one of his early writeups on the subject here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html and there's some discussion of some of Crockford's views [here](https://recalll.co/app/?q=javascript%20-%20Constructor%20pattern%20by%20douglas%20crockford).  There's a Crockford video somewhere (I can't see to find it right now) where he defends the non-prototype style.

---

So, it is logical to ask if you can combine the best of both.  No, not really.  In order to get access to the constructor closure the methods must be defined in the lexical scope of the constructor and to do that, they are not on the prototype.  Trying to assign them to the prototype inside the constructor creates a mess that is subject to all sorts of bugs so that's not feasible either.

Using an ES6 `weakMap` object, it is possible to make private instance data while using the prototype, though I would say it is generally more trouble that it is worth as it complicates just writing code and accessing private data - but it is possible.  You can see an implementation of the private variables using a `weakMap` in [Private instance members with weakmaps in JavaScript](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/01/21/private-instance-members-with-weakmaps-in-javascript/) and [Hiding Implementation Details with ECMAScript 6 WeakMaps](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/2014/01/13/hiding-implementation-details-with-e6-weakmaps.html).

---

I'd offer my opinion that hiding the fact that you're creating a new object by somehow removing the need for `new` is not really very Javascript-like or really very OO-like.  It should be obvious to someone reading the code when you are creating a new object and when you are just calling a function.  Using `new` with a capitalized constructor function makes that very obvious in Javascript and I consider that a good thing.  I would not purposely look to avoid that obvious intent in my code.

---

> If you store prototypes on the parent object, that can be a great way
>   to dynamically swap out functionality, and enable very flexible
>   polymorphism for your object instantiation.

It is true that if you use the prototype, it's a nice encapsulated object that contains all the methods for the object and it can make some polymorphism things easier.  But, you can also do polymorphism if you aren't using the prototype.

For example, suppose you have three objects that don't use the prototype and they assign all of their methods in their constructor and you want to create a mixin combination of all three.

You can create an object and then just call the other constructors and they will automatically initialize your object to be a combined object with the behavior of all three (assuming no conflicts in instance data property or method names).

```
function MyCombo() {
    ObjectA.call(this);
    ObjectB.call(this);
    ObjectC.call(this);
}
```

This will call each of the three constructors and they will each initialize their methods and instance variables.  In some ways, this is event simpler than if using the prototype.

If you had objects that were using the prototype, then you could do this:

```
function MyCombo() {
    ObjectA.call(this);
    ObjectB.call(this);
    ObjectC.call(this);
}

Object.assign(MyCombo.prototype, ObjectA.prototype, ObjectB.prototype, 
              ObjectC.prototype, {myComboMethod: function() {...}});

var x = new MyCombo();
x.methodA();
x.methodB();
```

---

> If I know that many objects are going to be created from the same FF
>   does this mean that I could switch that FF to using prototype methods?

It depends upon what tradeoffs work best for your code.  If you had 1000 methods and were creating 20,000 objects of that type, then I'd say you probably want to use the prototype so you could share all those methods.  If you don't have that many methods or aren't creating a lot of those types of objects or you have plenty of memory, then you may want to optimize for some other characteristic (like private data) and not use the prototype.  It's a tradeoff space. There is no single correct answer.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, I just had a thought. If one were to use a FF like in my original post:
`function FF(constructorArg) {
   var _privateName = constructorArg;

   var publicMessage = "Hello StackOverflow";

   function publicMethodGetName() {
      return _privateName;
   }

   return {
      publicMethodGetName: publicMethodGetName,
      publicMessage: publicMessage
   };
}`

and was sure that they would NEVER use the 'this' keyword inside the FF, I'm guessing that it would then be acceptable to do `var ff = new FF()`? Provides the ^ readability of 'new' without 'this' problems.

Comment: @user5508297 - I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve by creating your own object inside the constructor.

Comment: because it provides control over whether the methods are public or private.

Comment: If I use that style of methods - `function getCntr() {return cntr++;}` rather than your style `this.getCntr = function() {
        return cntr++;
    }` shouldn't it be ok for me do `var ff = new FF(); ff.getCntr();`? I'm not using 'this' so I avoid the reference problems that using 'new' has with factory functions.

Comment: This post discusses the problems with using the 'this' keyword and factory functions that I'm referring to: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e

Comment: But, like I say, they're not an issue if I NEVER use 'this' inside a factory function body?

Comment: @user5508297 - You don't have to return your own object in order to have private methods or private instance data as shown here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html.  In fact, returning your own object from the constructor or factory has nothing to do with creating private methods.  What creates private methods is creating a lasting closure that has data and/or functions in it and defining methods within that scope so they (and only they) can access the private info.