# How to write public fields in pure ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Is possible to have public field in an ES6 class like this:

```
class Device {

    public id=null;
    public name=null;

    constructor(id,name,token) {
        this.id = id;       // I want this field to be public
        this.name = id;     // I want this field to be public

        this.token = token; // this will be private
    }
}
```

I know that is easy to have private field—just by put them in constructor (like 'token' field in example code above)—but what about public fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 class variable alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Comment: What do you mean by "public fields"?  Regular instance variables are already publicly accessible properties - always have been (same in ES3 to ES6).  So your `id` and `name` properties are already accessible by anyone who has your object iinstance.  Your question, as it stands now, is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: my mistake - I don't check that fields declared in constructor are actually public - and the problem is with private fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if you assign something to a property of `this` inside a constructor, the field will be public. There are no private fields in ES6 classes.

```js
class Test {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const test = new Test("Kamil");
console.log(test.name); // "Kamil"
```