# Understanding ExtJs Class properties

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2

I try to understand how properties works in ExtJs class.
Refer to below code:

```js
Ext.define('My.sample.Person', {
    name: 'Unknown',
    food: undefined,
    foodList: [],
    constructor: function(name) {
        if (name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    },

    eat: function(foodType) {
        console.log(this.name + " is eating: " + foodType);
        this.food = foodType;
        this.foodList.push(foodType);
        //this.foodList = [foodType]
    },
    
    showFood:function() {
         console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.food);
    },
    
     showFoodList:function() {
         console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.foodList);
    }
});

var bob = Ext.create('My.sample.Person', 'Bob');
bob.eat("Salad"); 
bob.showFood(); 
bob.showFoodList(); 
console.log(bob)
var alan = Ext.create('My.sample.Person', 'alan');
console.log(alan)
alan.showFood();
alan.showFoodList();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
```

If you check the result of "alan", the food = undefined and foodList = ['salad'] because somehow foodList was assigned to prototype.

[image]

---

**Meanwhile, if you do like this, then it will behave normally like it should. Any idea why? What is the concept behind?**

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: But alan has not eaten any salad yet. :)

Comment: haha, yeah. exactly. 
but  this.foodList.push(foodType); will modify the prototype. 
it seems only array and object will do that, while string wont have this issue

Comment: You're right. Here is a good article. https://moduscreate.com/blog/a-dive-into-the-sencha-class-config-system/

Comment: yeah, i saw the article before, but doesnt really solve my puzzle.. because it focus more on config while i'm not using the config .. hmm..

Comment: This is what exactly your issue is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42129243/1068246

Comment: Thanks. Ya, i think that should answer it. 
only weird thing is by right, all the properties of the prototype should remain value as well. But in ExtJs, only object/array remain. Refer my example above, the "food" property get refreshed as undefined. 


`function MyClass(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
}

MyClass.prototype.items = [];

MyClass.prototype.item = 'test';

var c1 = new MyClass(1);

var c2 = new MyClass(2);

console.log(c2.items);  // returns an array of [1, 2]

console.log(c2.item); //returns 'test'`