# Class variables outside a class

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

Lets say that I have a class like this

```
class Vector {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }
}
```

How can i do something like this

```
class Vector {
    constructor() {
    }
    var x;
    var y;
}
var v = new Vector()
v.x = 3
v.y = 4
```

I basically want to declare my variables outside the constructor. Done some research. Found nothing

Comment: Do you want those variables act as a static one?

Comment: There is no need to declare it. You can still assign it after instance creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are talking about `Property Initialiazers`.

Your code could work fine if you modify it a little:

```
class Vector {
    constructor() {}

    x = 1;
    y = 2;
}

var v = new Vector();

console.log(v.x, v.y); // 1 2

v.x = 3
v.y = 4

console.log(v.x, v.y); // 3 4
```

Just keep in mind that this is currently a `stage-2` [proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/), so it won't work in any browser out of the box.

If **you are using babel** you can use [`transform-class-properties`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties) plugin though.

If **you are not using babel** there are some alternatives that you could use - they have been discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to setup babel with webpack

Comment: But do I have to give them values?

Comment: @Blaze349 Yes, although even something like `x = null;` would work if you're going to replace the value later.

Comment: If it's a stage 2 proposal then it's not part of ES7 (ES2016). ES2016 was released last year!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the properties after the instance is created:

```js
class Vector {
  constructor() {
    this.x = null;
    this.y = null;
  }
}

let v = new Vector();

v.x = 1;
v.y = 2;

console.log(v.x, v.y); // 1 2
```

**OR**

You can define the properties with `get` and `set` like so:

```js
class Vector {
  constructor() {
    this.xValue = null;
    this.yValue = null;
  }
  get x() {
    return this.xValue;
  }
  set x(newVal) {
    this.xValue = newVal;
  }
  get y() {
    return this.yValue;
  }
  set y(newVal) {
    this.yValue = newVal;
  }
}

let v = new Vector();

v.x = 1;
v.y = 2;

console.log(v.x, v.y); // 1 2
```

---

The second approach lets you manipulate the new value before setting it.

Example:

```js
class Vector {
  constructor() {
    this.xValue = null;
    this.yValue = null;
  }
  get x() {
    return this.xValue;
  }
  set x(newVal) {
    this.xValue = `The value of 'x' is ${newVal}.`;
  }
  get y() {
    return this.yValue;
  }
  set y(newVal) {
    this.yValue = `The value of 'y' is ${newVal}.`;
  }
}

let v = new Vector();

v.x = 1;
v.y = 2;

console.log(v.x, v.y); // The value of 'x' is 1. The value of 'y' is 2.
```