# React-Native add var into view tag

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this class containing a string and the variable:

```
class Number extends Component{
    var num = 8
    render(){
        return{
            <Text>The number is: </Text> + num
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error

```
Unexpected token (31:6)
var num = 8
    ^
```

Is there any way I can get the class to return both the text and the variable when used?

```
<Number/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ES6 (the way you declared your class), you can't declare variables the way you want to. Here is explanation [ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

What you can do is to add it inside constructor, or inside render method.

```
class Number extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.num = 8 // this is added as class property - option 1
        this.state = { num: 8 } //this is added as a local state of react component - option 2
    }
    render(){
        const num = 8; // or here as regular variable. option 3
        return{
            <Text>The number is: </Text> + this.num // for option 1
            // <Text>The number is: </Text> + this.state.num //for option 2
            // <Text>The number is: </Text> + num //for option 3                 
        }
    }
}
```