# How to call a class itself and not its instance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am class and its subclasses, where I am required to call a static method of a child from the parent. But how can I call the static method without knowing which child?

```
class Animal{
  static doSomething(){
    //How do i call the static talk here?
    //talk()
  }
}

class Human extends Animal{
  static talk(){
    return 'Hello!'
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  static talk(){
    return 'Bark!'
  }
}

Human.doSomething()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use class variables in the parent class's static methods in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47504534/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling context is the `Human` class, and the `talk` method is a property directly on it, so you simply call `this.talk()`:

```js
class Animal{
  static doSomething(){
    return this.talk();
  }
}

class Human extends Animal{
  static talk(){
    return 'Hello!'
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  static talk(){
    return 'Bark!'
  }
}

console.log(Human.doSomething())
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call `this.talk()` from inside the `doSomething` static method.

```js
class Animal{
  static doSomething(){
    console.log(this.talk());
  }
}

class Human extends Animal{
  static talk(){
    return 'Hello!'
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  static talk(){
    return 'Bark!'
  }
}

Human.doSomething()
```

In the context of a static method, `this` will refer to class object was called on (barring any code to change it).