# Different way for declare and initialize variable

Tags: react-native

Version A:

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
  dateArray = [];

  datePreparation(){
    this.dateArray.push( moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
  }
}
```

Version B:

```
const dateArray = [];
class MainScreen extends Component {

  datePreparation(){
    dateArray.push( moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
  }
}
```

Came across this 2 different way of declaring variable, wondering if there is any significant differences. On version A, why we can't initialize with `const/let/var` for variable `dateArray`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `dateArray` should not be shared among multiple `MainScreen` instances, version A is better.

For version A, `dateArray` is a [class member variable](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), don't need to declare with `var/let/const`. It's equal to

> constructor () { this.dateArray = [] }

And btw, if you are not using something like [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx), version A/B will not trigger rerender if `dateArray` changed.