# Declare and reuse variable in a React Class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With pure functions in React it's easy to make any variable you create reusable by any other nested functions:

```
const myComponent = props => {
  const {something} = props.nested;

  const nestedFunction = () => {
    if (something === "value") return true
  }

  const otherNestedFunction = () => {
    console.log(otherNestedFunction)
  }

  return (
    // markup
  )
}
```

Can you do something similar with a React class? At the moment Im having to repeat creating the variable.

```
class myComponent extends React.Component() {

  nestedFunction() {
    const {something} = props.nested;
    if (something === "value") return true
  }

  otherNestedFunction() {
    const {something} = props.nested;
    console.log(otherNestedFunction)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      // markup
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share variables among functions of an ES6 class, use member variables. React provides props as a member variable which you can access with `this.props`:

```
class myComponent extends React.Component() {

  nestedFunction() {
    if (this.props.nested === "value") return true
  }

  otherNestedFunction() {
    console.log(this.props.nested)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      // markup
    )
  }
}
```

Note that you should never assign or otherwise chance the value of any props. Instead, use state with `this.setState()` to update internal component state and trigger lifecycle events to update children components.