# Wrapping third party JS libraries in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn how to use 3rd party APIs like Google Map, or BrainTree Dropin UI, and make them into ReactJS components.

Along my research, I came across such an example of a project that wraps the Braintree (payment gateway) - https://github.com/Cretezy/braintree-web-drop-in-react/blob/master/src/index.js

Unfortunately I am not able to follow the code, in particular, I cannot understand the syntax in lines 22-23. They look like decorators, but I am not sure and/or how they work in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are talking about is the following:

```
class ... {
   ...

   wrapper;
   instance;

   ...
}
```

This is just a property declaration without giving a value, it's the same as:

```
class ... {
   ...

   wrapper = undefined;
   instance = undefined;

   ...
}
```

And nothing would actually happen if you removed that completely. If you inspect the code more, `wrapper` stores the DOM reference for the wrapping `<div>`, `instance` is the stored Braintree instance from `componentDidMount`.

It's possible ESLint rules enforce the declaration.

Answer (score 5):

**How to wrap third party libraries?**

There a lot of resources about the topic. You can start with the official React documentation as a first one - [Integrating with Other Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html).

Also there's already created React wrappers / integrations, with the libraries you asked for:

1. [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) - *A declarative Google Map React component using React*. Also the library has a [complete article how it works](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/).
2. [braintree-dropin-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree-dropin-react) - *React component to integrate Braintree Drop-In UI (V3)*.

**What's the purpose of the code you mention?**

It's just a [property declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986568/4312466). I guess it's there for the sake of clarity, but with or without `wrapper, instance` declarations, the code will still behave in the same way.