# Javascript Scope: Access class field within anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, scope, anonymous-function

I'm running into a funny issue in my (Javascript) code that I think has to do with scope. If this is the case, I'd like to understand scope in JS better.

I doubt this will be relevant, but I'm also working with React and D3.

The gist of my code is as follows:

```
// 1

export default class C extends Component {
    // 2

    componentDidUpdate() {
        // 3

        ...
        var node = svg.append('svg')
            .append('svg:image')
            .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {
                // 4

                return dict['foo'];
            });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the contents of an outside object within an anonymous function.

```
    dict = {
        foo: 'bar.svg'
    };
```

So far I've found that if I declare the above object in locations **3** or **4**, the code executes just fine. However, if I move the object declaration outside the method (**2**), or outside the class entirely (**1**), I get an error: `dict is not defined`.

What about locations 1 and 2 makes them unavailable for use within the anonymous function?

Comment: `return this.dict['foo'];`

Comment: AFAIK you can't declare class variables within a class declaration as yet.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986568/5217142) mentions using babel (which you would for react) may support this but I don't know how it is transpiled. The ECMAScript proposal to add class variables may be [this one](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use an arrow function.

```js
export default class C extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        ...
        var node = svg.append('svg')
            .append('svg:image')
            .attr('xlink:href', (d) => this.dict['foo']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, in an arrow function I'm able to use `this.dict['foo']`, but not in a traditional function. The follow discussion of arrow functions vs. regular functions helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/7531146

Comment: That's correct. Here's another example of how to use the arrow functions with class variables: https://codepen.io/rustydev/project/editor/DVMNze

Answer (score -2):

There are two scopes in javascript. Local scope and global scope. If you have function like

```
TestFunc() {
// here variable 'a' local variable in this function
// and you can't access 'a' outside of this function
 var a = 'test';
}

but if you have a class like
class TestClass {
 // here 'b' is a global variable of this class
 // and it can be accessed from any of the method of this class using 'this' keyword
 b: string;

 // example of method
 TestGFunction() {
 // here 'b' is a global variable of class 'TestClass'
  this.b = 'test3';
}
}
```

Hope it may help you to understand the concept of local and global scope in javascript.

Comment: Do you get any error messages on the console if you try to compile `TestClass`?

Comment: My above code is just as sample for understanding the concept.

Comment: But it doesn't work. You can't define variables in class declarations.

Comment: yes I know, updated the code though and thanks for the suggestion.