# Unable to fetch object value and define constant and static variable in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6, koa

I have the following code:

```
'use strict';

const Request = require('request');

class CryptoKetHandlers {

    static async coins(ctx) {
        try {
            var CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/json';
            console.log(`## Hitting cryptoket coins api for coins list ...`);
            var res = await Request.get({
                url: 'https://api.cryptoket.io/info/currencies',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE,
                }
            }, (err, res, body) => {
                //console.log(`Inside response ... res: ${res} err: ${err} body: ${body}`);
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`#### ERROR :: API RESP :: CryptoKetHandlers :: coins :: exception :: ${err}`);
                    ctx.throw(500);
                } else {
                    let res = {};
                    res.body = body;
                    res.status = 200;
                    return res;
                }
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(`#### ERROR :: CryptoKetHandlers :: coins :: exception :: ${ex}`);
            ctx.throw(500);
        }
        console.log(`######### Final Response :: status - ${res.status} body - ${res.body} res :: ${res}`);
        ctx.body = res;
        ctx.status = 200;
    }

}

module.exports = CryptoKetHandlers;
```

I am from Java background and new to koa & nodejs so wondering if how can I achieve the following things:

1. Why res.status and res.body always return undefined?
2. How can I declare CONTENT_TYPE as a class variable should be const & static?

What is want to achieve is:

- Return all these err, res, body parameters from Request.get and
  process it somewhere else (in another class function).

  - Make all the reusable variable class level so that no need to define again & again.
  - If you have some suggestions to make my code more robust and cleaner.

I tried various ways by googling but no success so asking here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why res.status and res.body always return undefined?

Firstly, `Request.get()` should return a `Promise` to work for the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to work.

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is resolved, that is fulfilled or rejected, and to resume execution of the async function after fulfillment. **When resumed, the value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.**

Second, You're accidentally replacing return value `res` with the other `res` in `(err, res, body) => {}`. Instead, we can return the return value as plain objects.

Making those changes,

```
'use strict';

let request = require('request');

const CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/json';

function makeRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get({
      url: 'https://api.cryptoket.io/info/currencies',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': CONTENT_TYPE,
      }
    }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`#### ERROR :: API RESP :: CryptoKetHandlers :: coins :: exception :: ${err}`);
        return reject(err);
      }

      // return as object
      return resolve({ 
        body: body,
        status: 200
      });
    });
  });
}

class CryptoKetHandlers {

  static async coins(ctx) {
    try {
      console.log(`## Hitting cryptoket coins api for coins list ...`);
      let res = await makeRequest();
      console.log(`######### Final Response :: status - ${res.status} body - ${res.body} res :: ${res}`);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(`#### ERROR :: CryptoKetHandlers :: coins :: exception :: ${ex}`);
    }
  }

}
```

Since I replaced `var` with `let`. I've moved the final logging within `try`block.

> 2. How can I declare CONTENT_TYPE as a class variable should be const & static?

The proposal for this is now underway. You can check [ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives) for more information.

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal it is subjective ;)