# How to set a variable on prototype in ES6 Classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
class SomeClass {

  someMethod() {
    // some code
  }

  someMoreMethod() {
    // some more code
  }

}

var someInstance = new someClass();
```

We know that in the code above, methods `someMethod` and `someMoreMethod` would get attached to the prototype of `someInstance` object. But, what if we want to attach some property (not method) to the prototype. I tried doing the following but it throws error:

```
class SomeClass {

    someProperty = "Some Value";

    someMethod() {
      // some code
    }

    someMoreMethod() {
      // some more code
    }

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Comment: "*set a variable on prototype*" - you can create a property, but you better make it constant not variable as you probably don't want globally shared state amongst your instances. Of course, a constant could also be placed anywhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ES6 classes do not currently support fields.
However, you can add properties to the prototype directly:

```
SomeClass.prototype.someProperty = "Some Value";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for defining non-function prototype fields, so they need to be added manually:

```
SomeClass.prototype.someProperty = "Some Value"

// a nicer way to define multiple at once:
Object.assign(SomeClass.prototype, {
   someProperty: "Some Value",
   anotherProperty: "Another Value",
})
```

### Anonymous Classes

If you need to define an "anonymous" class (e.g. within an expression, without defining a variable), you can use a helper function, such as:

```
function def_proto(cls, proto) {
    Object.assign(cls.prototype, proto)
    return cls
}

console.log(
    def_proto(class {
        someMethod() {
            return this.someProperty
        }
    }, {
        someProperty: "Some Value",
    })
)
```

### Static Initialization Blocks

This feature is not widely supported yet. But in the future, the previous example can be written as:

```
console.log(
    class {
        someMethod() {
            return this.someProperty
        }
        static {
            // Note: in static methods, `this` refers to the CLASS
            this.prototype.someProperty = "Some Value"
        }
    }
)
```