# How to define a static variable inside a JS class

Tags: javascript, class

I'm building a static class to store data inside an a array and i want to declare a static variable but i don't know how to do it on javascript.

JS code:

```
class GCache {

    // Define cache variable
    static cache = {}; // <--- that is what i don't know how to do

    /**
     * Check if data is on cache
     * @param {*} id 
     */
    static isOnCache(id){
        return this.cache.hasOwnProperty(id);
    }

    /**
     * Add data to cache
     * @param {*} id 
     * @param {*} json 
     */
    static addToCache(id, json){
        if(this.isOnCache(id)) return;
        this.cache[id] = json;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain data from cache
     * @param {*} id 
     */
    static getFromCache(id){
        if(this.isOnCache(id)) return;
        return this.cache[id];
    }

}
```

Thank you <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 class variable alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In up-to-date JavaScript environments, you can use the `static` keyword when inside a class to assign properties to the instance itself - the code in your question works fine now.

```js
class SomeClass {
    static someStaticProperty = {}
}
console.log(SomeClass.someStaticProperty);
```

---

In older environments, and at the time the question was originally posted, non-function properties couldn't be added to a class itself inside the class definition. It looks ugly, but you'll have to assign the property *outside* of the class definition:

```
class GCache {
  ...
}
GCache.cache = {};
```

Also note that your `getFromCache` function probably has a bug: you probably want to return early if the `id` being searched for does *not* exist in the cache:

```
if(!this.isOnCache(id)) return;
```

```js
class GCache {
    /**
     * Check if data is on cache
     * @param {*} id 
     */
    static isOnCache(id){
        return this.cache.hasOwnProperty(id);
    }

    /**
     * Add data to cache
     * @param {*} id 
     * @param {*} json 
     */
    static addToCache(id, json){
        if(this.isOnCache(id)) return;
        this.cache[id] = json;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain data from cache
     * @param {*} id 
     */
    static getFromCache(id){
        if(!this.isOnCache(id)) return;
        return this.cache[id];
    }

}
GCache.cache = {};
GCache.addToCache('myid', 'data');
console.log(GCache.getFromCache('myid'));
```

But, in this case, it would probably be easier to use a plain object, rather than a class. The class isn't being used to instantiate anything, after all, and with an object, you can both define `cache` *inside the object*, and reduce the syntax noise by getting rid of all the `static`s:

```js
const GCache = {
  cache: {},
  isOnCache(id) {
    return this.cache.hasOwnProperty(id);
  },
  addToCache(id, json) {
    if (this.isOnCache(id)) return;
    this.cache[id] = json;
  },
  getFromCache(id) {
    if (!this.isOnCache(id)) return;
    return this.cache[id];
  }
}
GCache.addToCache('myid', 'data');
console.log(GCache.getFromCache('myid'));
```

---

There is currently a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features) allowing you to set static non-method properties onto a class. It's currently at Stage 2, which means it's expected to eventually be implemented officially. Once it lands, the code:

```
class GCache {
  ...
}
GCache.cache = {};
```

can be replaced by:

```
class GCache {
  static cache = {};
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's sad to read that js doesn't support it jet. (<3 bug fixed)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean static variable for all instance of the class,
declare: 
`GCache.cache = {}` 
below your class declaration

Answer (score 0):

Babel's [plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) is probably what you're looking for. It enables support for static variables/methods inside the class declaration.