# Where should a state be defined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, typescript3.0

What is the difference between these two constructs of defining state in React?

```
class ProductsPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: []
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

and this:

```
class ProductsPage extends Component {
  state = {
    products: []
  };
  ...
}
```

Both of them work well when coded in ES6. However, the lower one doesn't seem to work in typescript 3. I have the following:

```
interface IState {
  products: IProduct[];
}

class ProductsPage extends Component<{}, IState> {
  state = {
    products: []
  };


  public componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ products });
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="page-container">
        <ul className="product-list">
          {this.state.products.map(p => (
            <li className="product-list-item" key={p.id}>
              {p.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the ts compiler flagged an error saying: Property id does not exist on type 'never'

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second form is [class properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which is a stage 3 JavaScript proposal (meaning it's not part of the language yet). Adding properties on the constructor is the [old ES2015 way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528967/es6-class-variable-alternatives/22986568#22986568) (called maximally minimal classes).

In your case there is no functional difference.

TypeScript requires you to declare class fields for type safety - hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

How to define the state for a React component is as subjective as the coding styles React promotes itself. Usually I go the very strict route which looks as follows:

```
type State = {
    someStateVar: number[];
};

export class MyComponent extends Component<{}, State> {
    public readonly state: State = {
        someStateVar: [],
    };

    public async componentDidMount() {
        // Dynamically fetch data (maybe via axios) and populate the new state
        const data = await axios.get<number[]>(...);
        this.setState({ someStateVar: data });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I explicitly mark `state` as readonly just make sure, nobody attempts to write directly to it (even though IDEs and linters can check for those errors without the precaution nowadays).

Another reason why I prefer to not set the state manually with an assigment is that it might encourage wrong handling of state. You are never to assign something directly to `state` in a class method without the use of `setState`.

Furthermore I am basically defining the defaults right away and populating the state with dynamic data in `componentDidMount`. This approach allows you to keep the code concise by dropping an explicit constructor definition as you should move such an initialization to `componentDidMount` anyways and use the constructor only for binding methods if you don't use the class member arrow notation for those in the first place.