# JavaScript prototypal inheritance does this code differs one from the other?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have a question about JS prototyping:

If I have the following constructor:

```
function Person(name) {
     if (!(this instanceof Person))
         return new Person(name);
     this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello from " + this.name);
}
```

Here I have a method `sayHello` bound to the prototype of Person, which is more memory efficient that this:

```
function Person(name) {
     if (!(this instanceof Person))
         return new Person(name);
     this.name = name;
     this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello from " + this.name);
     }
}
```

Just a glimpse:

Prototypal person:

[image]

Not-prototypal person:

[image]

As you see, the reference to the `sayHello` **Function** will be "shared" across all the person created, instead of just creating a new Function for each instantiated person. `this` will then mutate to point to the correct person whenever it is used inside the `sayHello()` context when `sayHello()` is called on **that** specific person.

Now, another variant:

```
function Person(name) {
     if (!(this instanceof Person))
         return new Person(name);
     this.name = name;
     this.__proto__.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello from " + this.name);
     }
}
```

And the output is the same as for `Person.prototype.sayHello`, meaning that `sayHello` is shared across different persons.

But is there a difference between this two approaches? I guess no, because:

`Person.prototype === bob.__proto__ // true`

So really, when one should use the former (`Person.prototype.*` outside the constructor function) instead of the latter (`this.__proto__.*` inside the constructor function)?

Comment: **probably not the answer, just reference purpose** -- Did you check these good questions already? 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?rq=1 -- 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064731/good-example-of-javascripts-prototype-based-inheritance?rq=1

Comment: Always! Why would you want to mutate the prototype *every time* the constructor is called? Even though the method(s) would still be shared, every call to the constructor creates a new version of the method and throws away the old one. Just create the method once and be done with it.

Comment: @FelixKling That's a good reason, but beside this, there aren't any other differences, right?

Comment: Not from a structural perspective. But your are still cresting a copy of the same function, and external code could keep a reference to an old copy around.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you, what do you mean with "cresting a copy of the same function"?

Comment: Ah stupid auto-correct. It supposed to be "creating".

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Felix's comments.

The version that reads:

```
this.__proto__.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello from " + this.name);
}
```

shouldn't be used.

Each and every time that the enclosing constructor is invoked the code above will also be run, creating a *new* copy of that anonymous function, and overwriting the reference currently held in the `prototype`.

Any code that happens to hold a reference to the previous instance of that function will continue to point to that old version.

In memory efficiency terms it's very similar to writing `this.sayHello = function(...)` because none of the instances actually share the same copy of the function.  In code efficiency terms it's arguably worse (albeit equivalent to using `Person.prototype.sayHello = ...)` because every invocation requires an ascent up the prototype chain.