# What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

What does the following code do:

```
WeatherWidget.prototype = new Widget;
```

where `Widget` is a constructor, and I want to extend the Widget 'class' with a new function `WeatherWidget`.

What is the **`new`** keyword doing there and what would happen if it is left out?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
WeatherWidget.prototype = new Widget;
```

The `new` keyword calls `Widget` as a constructor and the return value is assigned to the `prototype` property.  (If you would omit `new`, you would not call `Widget` unless you added an argument list, `()`. However, calling `Widget` that way might not be possible. It would certainly have the potential to *spoil the global namespace* if it is not strict mode code and the implementation is conforming to ECMAScript Ed. 5.x there, because then `this` in the constructor would refer to ECMAScript’s global object.)

But this approach actually comes from a [really viral](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prototype+%3D+new%22&filter=0) [*bad example* in the old Netscape JavaScript 1.3 Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6409-10/obj2.htm#1008404) (mirrored at Oracle, formerly Sun).

This way, your `WeatherWidget` instances will all inherit from the *same* `Widget` instance. The prototype chain will be:

```
[new WeatherWidget()] → [new Widget()] → [Widget.prototype] → …
```

This can be useful, but most of the time you would not want it to happen.  You should not do that here unless you want all your `WeatherWidget` instances to *share among them* the *property values* they inherit from this `Widget` instance, and only *through it*, from `Widget.prototype`.  Another problem is that you need to call the parent constructor this way, which may not allow to be called without arguments as you do, or would not initialize properly. It certainly has nothing to do with emulation of class-based inheritance as known, e.g., from Java.

The proper way to implement class-based inheritance in these prototype-based languages is (originally devised by [Lasse Reichstein Nielsen in `comp.lang.javascript` in 2003, for cloning objects](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/5d06e72e55d5bf11)):

```
function Dummy () {}
Dummy.prototype = Widget.prototype;
WeatherWidget.prototype = new Dummy();
WeatherWidget.prototype.constructor = WeatherWidget;
```

The `constructor` prototype property should be fixed as well, so that your `WeatherWidget` instances `w` would have `w.constructor === WeatherWidget` as expected, and not `w.constructor === Widget`. However, be aware that it is enumerable afterwards.

This way, `WeatherWidget` instances will inherit properties through the prototype chain, but will not share property values among them, because they inherit from `Widget.prototype` through `Dummy` which has no own properties:

```
[new WeatherWidget()] → [new Dummy()] → [Widget.prototype] → …
```

In implementations of ECMAScript Ed. 5 and later, you can and should use

```
WeatherWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype, {
  constructor: {value: WeatherWidget}
});
```

instead. This has the additional advantage that the resulting `constructor` property is [not writable, enumerable, or configurable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1).

The parent constructor will only be called if you call it explicitly, from `WeatherWidget`, for example with

```
function WeatherWidget (…)
{
  Widget.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

See also [`Function.prototype.extend()`](https://github.com/PointedEars/JSX/blob/master/object.js#L3457-L3709) in my [JSX:object.js](https://github.com/PointedEars/JSX/blob/master/object.js) for how to generalize this.  Using that code, it would become

```
WeatherWidget.extend(Widget);
```

My `Function.prototype.extend()` takes an optional second argument with which you can easily augment the prototype of `WeatherWidget` instances:

```
WeatherWidget.extend(Widget, {
  foo: 42,
  bar: "baz"
});
```

would be equivalent to

```
WeatherWidget.extend(Widget);
WeatherWidget.prototype.foo = 42;
WeatherWidget.prototype.bar = "baz";
```

You will still need to call the parent constructor explicitly in the child constructor, though; that part cannot reasonably be automated.  But my `Function.prototype.extend()` adds a `_super` property to the `Function` instance which makes it easier:

```
function WeatherWidget (…)
{
  WeatherWidget._super.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Other people have implemented similar extensions.

Comment: +1 for despising the bad approach, -1 for not mentioning `Object.create` :-)

Comment: +1, fixed. I will see if `Object.create()` is worth using in a branch in `Function.prototype.extend()`.

Comment: This was very interesting to read and learn. In your example using Dummy you wrote `WeatherWidget.prototype = new Dummy();`, in my line the brackets are missing. What difference does that make?

Comment: @Kai Thank you. The difference is syntactical, not semantical. Consider it good code style. Noticed how the program changes – in that the constructor is not called anymore – when you are omitting `new` from your version? With an argument list the call of the constructor as a function might still fail, but at least it does not fail silently.

Comment: That is, if the constructor tested `this` or used strict mode.

Comment: @PointedEars, using `Object.defineProperty(WeatherWidget.prototype, "constructor", {value:WeatherWidget})` should solve the enumerate problem.

Comment: @Mouser Of course, but that requires an implementation of ES 5.x or newer, and then you can use `Object.create(…)` in the first place. See further below :)

Comment: @PointedEars Is it safe to commit to `Object.create()` now (it hasn't been 10 years since your post yet)? It seems all browsers support it.

Comment: @wcochran As always, it depends on your target environments (“all browsers” really means “all *browser* versions *I [you] have tested with*”). See the [ECMAScript Support Matrix](http://PointedEars.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/?filter=Object\.create#features-table) for the test cases and results. The feature is not going to go away, so it is safe with anything *recent* (for example, all environments that use Google V8 JavaScript as ECMAScript implementation). I recommend that you use `Object.create()` and emulate it where it is not available (shim). But not all of its features can be emulated.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, you might want to update that statement about "restricted environments". `Object.create` can and should be used on the Web now (and if supporting old IE is a must, then it can be shimmed using that `Dummy` trick).

Comment: @Bergi It is not that simple. It does not suffice to determine that the method is there (existence), but you also need to make sure that it works properly if it is there (functionality). And keep in mind that you cannot emulate non-`[[Enumerable]]`. With that said, of the major implementations I/we have tested, so far only [that in the second-newest Opera version did not pass all of the tests](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix/?filter=Object.create). They do not include the non-`[[Enumerable]]` test yet, though.

Comment: I don't think non-enumerabilty is a deal breaker here. Btw, that test case seems to fail in Opera because `eval` in a `catch` statement does not work as specced, but the test uses it - try out `var e = "variable"; try { throw "lexical"; } catch(e) { console.log(eval("e")); }`. `Object.create` behaves as expected actually. (Seems I wrote you an email about this some 2 years ago already?)

Comment: @Bergi *If* you emulate `Object.create()`, you need to emulate it *properly* because then it might not only be used for inheritance; it has a second parameter. Non-`[[Writable]]` *can* be emulated in many known, non-`[[Enumerable]]` and non-`[[Configurable]]` *might* be emulated in some environments. As for the test case, I have received your e-mail, kept it, and not replied to it because I have not found the time to determine the reliability of your test case, and a compatible workaround for the problem, if it is that, yet.

Comment: @PointedEars: I think `if (errorHandlers == "e") return e;` would help the majority of cases; if you want to make sure just deprecate `evil` code strings and always pass a function (the identify function instead of `"e"`).

Comment: @Bergi Your suggestion cannot work, and I cannot replace `eval(…)` in the ECMAScript _Support_ Matrix; that would defy its purpose. (This discussion does not belong here, and discussions in general do not belong on Stack Overflow.  Please, if necessary, continue it elsewhere. Previously, a link to a chat was offered when there were too many comments on an answer, but I do not see that anymore.)

Comment: In your example `WeatherWidget.prototype = new Dummy();`  , `new Dummy()` will return an object whose prototype is `Widget.prototype`. If it was `new Widget()`, it'll also return an object  whose prototype is `Widget.prototype`. What's the difference..? Am I missing something..?

Comment: @TJ Your observation is correct. The difference is: With the "bad" approach, “your `WeatherWidget` instances will all inherit from the *same* `Widget` instance” *before* they inherit from `Widget.prototype`. This makes them dependent on the `Widget` constructor, and to share the values of all properties that are provided by `Widget.prototype` and defined in the `Widget` constructor, through `WeatherWidget.prototype`.

Comment: `You should not do that here unless you want all your WeatherWidget instances to share among them the property values they inherit from this Widget instance, and only through it, from Widget.prototype.` Why is this a problem? It sounds exactly like how inheritance should work. One object has an effect on downstream properties.

Answer (score 7):

*According to some odd Javascript rules, `new Widget` actually invokes the constructor rather than returning a reference to the constructor.  This question actually answers the question the difference between `var a = new Widget()` and `var a = Widget()`.*

In simple words, the `new` keyword tells Javascript to call the function `Widget` under a different set of rules than a regular function call.  Going off the top of my head, the ones I remember are:

1. There is a brand new object created
2. `Widget` can use the `this` keyword to refer to that object.
3. If `Widget` does not return anything, this new object will be created.
4. This object will inherit a few additional properties that will indicate it was created by `Widget` that are used to track down property chains.

Without the `new` keyword, a call to widget would

1. If in strict mode, `this` will be set to `undefined.`
2. Otherwise, `this` will refer to the global object.  (Called `window` by the browser.)
3. If the function does not return anything, then `undefined` will be returned.

Reference: 
[`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: Searching for `javascript constructor` here at SO will fill in many more details.

Comment: Missing obligatory link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new :-)

Comment: Please note that his code has no brackets - it would be just an assignment of the constructor function

Comment: @Bergi -- In Javascript constructors the parens are optional for some reason I've never figured out.  [See this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439290/parentheses-after-new-function-optional)

Comment: Yes, and that is why it would be no invocation without the `new` keyword - because the OP has omitted them

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher You are missing the point. The original code has no parameter list. If you would omit the `new` keyword, the code would not call the constructor at all. So your answer actually does *not* answer correctly the question what would happen if one omitted `new`.

Comment: How does this explain the difference between `a = new Widget()` and `a = Widget()` in way different than saying `new` invokes a function as a constructor?

Answer (score 5):

```
WeatherWidget.prototype = new Widget;
```

does create a new instance of the `Widget` constructor and use it as `WeatherWidget`'s prototype object. Using the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) creates the new object, sets up the inheritance chain of it to `Widget.prototype`, and applies the constructor function on it (where you can set up individual properties'n'methods, or create private-scoped variables).

Without the `new` keyword it would be an assignment of the `Widget` function to the `prototype` property - which does not make any sense. If you'd add the optional brackets (i.e. `Widget()`), it would invoke the function normally, but not as a constructor on a new instance, but with the global object as context. See also the [reference for the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Notice that you should not really use this code. As said, it creates a new instance by invoking the constructor function. But the purpose is only to create an *empty* object that inherits from the `Widget`s prototype object, not to instantiate something (which could do some harm, depending on the code). Instead, you should use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (or its [popular shim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10141086/1048572)):

```
WeatherWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype);
```

see also [Javascript basic inheritance vs Crockford prototypical inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11812648/1048572)

Comment: Interesting approach, but please see my updated answer: You would want to fix the `constructor` property as well. And that is where the "popular shim" for `Object.create()` fails – *must* fail even if updated – because you cannot emulate non-enumerability. You can only `hasOwnProperty()`-filter it out later. That still leaves write-onlyness and non-configurability, which can be only partially emulated (depending on the implementation).

Comment: Yes, passing `{constructor:{value:WeatherWidget}}` as the second argument should be done, and you might need to use a less popular shim :-) However, I am not sure which code depends on a correctly set `constructor` property?

Comment: I have an `isInstance()` method on some of my constructors that does. More precise than duck typing alone.

Answer (score 3):

In plain english you're extending one class with another. A prototype can only be an object so you set `WeatherWidget`'s prototype to a new instance of `Widget`. If you removed the `new` keyword you would be setting the prototype to the literal constructor function which doesn't do anything.

```
var Appendages = function(){
  this.legs = 2
};
var Features = function() {
   this.ears = 4;
   this.eyes = 1;
}

// Extend Features class with Appendages class.
Features.prototype = new Appendages;
var sara = new Features();
sara.legs;
// Returns 2.
```

Understanding that the prototype can be any object, something like this would also work:

```
var appendages = {
  legs : 2
};
var Features = function() {
   this.ears = 4;
   this.eyes = 1;
}

// Extend Features class with Appendages class.
Features.prototype = appendages;
var sara = new Features();
sara.legs;
// Returns 2.
```

In JavaScript, if the key isn't found on the object, it checks the parents object you extended it from. Hence you can change items on the parent object on the fly like so:

```
var appendages = {
  legs : 2
};
var Features = function() {
   this.ears = 4;
   this.eyes = 1;
}

// Extend Features class with Appendages class.
Features.prototype = appendages;
var sara = new Features();
sara.legs;
// Returns 2.
appendages.hair = true;
sara.hair;
// Returns true.
```

Note that this all happens during instantiation which means you can't just switch out the prototype after you've created the object:

```
var foo = {name : 'bob'};
var bar = {nachos : 'cheese'};
foo.prototype = bar;
foo.nachos;
// undefined
```

However, all modern browsers come with this newer `__proto__` method, which allows you to do it:

```
var foo = {name : 'bob'};
var bar = {nachos : 'cheese'};
foo.__proto__ = bar;
foo.nachos
// "cheese"
```

Read up more on understanding JavaScript prototypes [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/).
This [article](http://pivotallabs.com/users/pjaros/blog/articles/1368-javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword) from Pivotal Labs is also really good.

Comment: What is that `Appendages` function good for, why do you need an instance (including a prototype object) of it there?

Comment: Bergi: I just added a 3rd example to show that off. Objects can extend on each other up a chain so it enables you to reuse and build code. In a theoretical example, all vehicles have similarities including an engine. We can build that into a base class, but not all vehicles have four wheels. So we can build one car class and one motorcycle class on top of it and reuse the core code. In real life, I use the Backbone.js framework. A lot of views are similar where I need to show a list of items. By making a base list class, I can extend it to create 20 different list pages with very little bloat.

Comment: It's better for `Appendages` to be a class constructor instead of an object so that you can initialize it with various options. So it could be an "engine" class where you can pass in the size of the engine while still making it reusable.

Comment: Nah, a "class constructor" to instantiate prototype objects is usually a bad idea, the problem of similiar classes should be solved otherwise.

Comment: You're right if what you passed to the constructor turned it into a completely different object, but for a minor setting I disagree.

Answer (score 2):

[`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)  is important for *prototype* inheritance; i.e.
Create a constructor with a method

```
var Obj = function(){};
Obj.prototype = {};
Obj.prototype.foo = function(){console.log('foo');};
```

Make a second constructor to extend the first with

```
var ExObj = function(){};
```

Now, if we prototype without `new`,

```
ExObj.prototype = Obj;
(new ExObj).foo(); // TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'foo'
```

Which means we haven't inherited from the prototype of `Obj`, however, if we prototype with `new`

```
ExObj.prototype = new Obj();
(new ExObj).foo(); // console logs 'foo'
```

Furthermore, adding new things to the prototype of `ExObj` doesn't make any changes to it's base, `Obj`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions are "MULTIPLE(2) PERSONALITIES"!!!

They are regular-functions with input and output, which we call like `function()`.

Also they are constructors of JS-objects, when we use the `new` keyword.  >>>BUT<<< the new created objects are NOT INSTANCES of the constructors (like the objects of classes in class-based inheritance). The new objects are instances of the object of the `prototype` property of the constructor.

Then in `WeatherWidget.prototype =` you put the object you want to inherit its properties to the objects the constructor will create, which usually is `new function()` and not a function.

JavaScript created HUGE confusion in the programming community by naming the objects created by constructors, INSTANCES of them with the `instanceof` keyword.
`> function f(){}`
`undefined`
`> new f() instanceof f`
`true`

Comment: Well, you can always do `var o = Object.create(f.prototype); o.constructor(); f.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o)` :-)