# How do you define an OOP class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

Based on my observation, the book that I am reading about JavaScript states that there's an OOP with JavaScript? It doesn't tell much about it, I mean it wasn't explained how to define a class. Can someone give me a sample snippet?

Thanks

Comment: which book, which code, why, what, accept some answers

Comment: @Andy E: Six not accepted questions within one week is not that bad.

Comment: @Gumbo: Yes, but it starts out as 6 in one week and grows from that.  I think it's best to prompt someone to mark some answers as early as possible :-)

Comment: @sasori: If any of the answers to your previous questions were satisfactory and/or solved your problem, you may want to mark them  "accepted". This is considered good etiquette, and will encourage more users to answer any of your future questions. In any case, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @sasori: Please read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet may help you getting started with JavaScript's class-less, instance-based objects:

```
function getArea() {  
   return (this.radius * this.radius * 3.14);  
}  

function getCircumference() {  
   var diameter = this.radius * 2;  
   var circumference = diameter * 3.14;  
   return circumference;  
}

function Circle(radius) {  
   this.radius = radius;  
   this.getArea = getArea;  
   this.getCircumference = getCircumference;  
}

var bigCircle = new Circle(100);  
var smallCircle = new Circle(2);

alert(bigCircle.getArea());            // displays 31400  
alert(bigCircle.getCircumference());   // displays 618  
alert(smallCircle.getArea());          // displays 12.56  
alert(smallCircle.getCircumference()); // displays 12.56
```

Example from: [SitePoint - JavaScript Object-Oriented Programming](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/oriented-programming-1)

Comment: Your example does not use prototype based inheritance at all. This is certainly a valid way to do inheritance, but don't claim that this is prototype based inheritance.

Comment: @Keith: Updated my answer: with more accurate terminology... Nevertheless, I think the above can still be considered an example of a prototype-based programming: In prototype-based systems there are two methods of constructing new objects, through cloning of an existing object, and through ex nihilo ("from nothing") object creation. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming#Object_construction

Comment: @DanielVassallo Thank you for this example, makes it easy coming from Java :)

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript is **[Prototype based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)** and not class based.

> Prototype-based programming is a style
>   of object-oriented programming in
>   which classes are not present, and
>   behavior reuse (known as inheritance
>   in class-based languages) is performed
>   via a process of cloning existing
>   objects that serve as prototypes. This
>   model can also be known as class-less,
>   prototype-oriented or instance-based
>   programming. Delegation is the
>   language feature that supports
>   prototype-based programming.

Comment: But you can still emulate aspects of class based inheritance and make it feel like regular classes. http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [this book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) for a concise, precise explanation of both how to use JS's prototypal inheritance as well as how to emulate classical OO inheritance in JS.

[image: JavaScript: The good parts]

Comment: Yes. There are also excellent explanations on Douglas Crockford's web site (www.crockford.com).

Comment: You might find the videos he's done useful, too - here are a couple.  
http://ajaxian.com/archives/douglas-crockford-video-advanced-javascript http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111593/1710507

Answer (score 3):

Any function in javascript can be used to create an object:

Example:

```
function MyPoint(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.distanceTo = getDistance;
}

function getDistance(p) {
  var dx = this.x-p.x;
  var dy = this.y-p.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

var p0 = new MyPoint(1, 2);
var p1 = new MyPoint(2, 3);

window.alert('The distance is ' + p0.distanceTo(p1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple different ways

```
if (typeof FFX == "undefined") {
    FFX = {};
}

//Static class
FFX.Util = ({
     return {
      method:function(){
      }
})();

FFX.Util.method(); 



//Instance class
FFX.Util2 = ({
    // private method
    var methodA=function(){
      alert("Hello");
    };
     return {
      method:function(){
      //Call private method
        methodA();
      }
});
var x= new FFX.Util();
x.method();
```

Another way

```
function MyClass(){
}

/* privileged functions */
MyClass.prototype.hello = function(){
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Also you could see how jquery, prototype and alike handle classes and see if thats fits you needs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one standard way of doing OOP in JavaScript. Everyone uses slightly different class/instance systems and most books fudge the issue. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1597560) for discussion of ways to work with OO in JS and pick your favourite.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript everything is a object. So even a function is a object. So in js (less then < version 2), function makes classes (which are first class objects themselves). Go [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml), [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html) and [here](http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/archive/2006/05/object-oriented-javascript/)for understanding better