# Should this JavaScript thing be an object or a singleton class?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm working on a JavaScript software that bears resemblance to Windows. It has a desktop, taskbar, etc. and I'm wondering whether I should make the desktop a class or an object?

I'm thinking about making a process list array that holds all instances of objects. It would hold an instance of desktop. Does this make sense? Or should I just have one global class called desktop that I don't instantiate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether I should make
>   the desktop a class or an object

That's an easy decision, as in JavaScript there are no classes -- just objects.

JavaScript is a [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) language and not [class-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming).

You may want to check the following Stack Overflow posts for further reading on the topic:

- [How do you define an OOP class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221401/how-do-you-define-an-oop-class-in-javascript)
- [What are good JavaScript OOP resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908443/what-are-good-javascript-oop-resources)
- [Is JavaScript object-oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107464/is-javascript-object-oriented)
- [Object Oriented questions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444170/object-oriented-questions-in-javascript)
- [Advantages of prototype based OO over class based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879061/advantages-of-prototype-based-oo-over-class-based)
- [OO Javascript : Definitive explanation of variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99927/oo-javascript-definitive-explanation-of-variable-scope)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't have classes, only objects. You can chose how to initialize that object, either as a singleton (`var desktop = {};`) or with a constructor (`var desktop = new Desktop();`).

I usually make a singleton object, because there is no point in making the constructor if you are only ever going to construct it once. I know others like to make an anonymous self executing function (`var desktop = (function(){return {}; })();`), but it's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: So, do you think I should instantiate an object (new Desktop()) rather than having a static singleton object?

Comment: Is there a particular reason as to why this would be a better option?