# How to get a constructor function to inherit from a constructor function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

So I'm learning Javascript and all its' prototype goodness, and I am stumped over the following:

Say I have this

```
var Animal = function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k , l, m, n){
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   //...etc...
};

var x = new Animal(1,2,3....);
```

Now how do I create a Cat constructor function that inherits from the Animal constructor function such that I don't have to type the super long arguments again?

In other words I don't want to be doing this:

```
var Cat = function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k , l, m, n){
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   //...etc...
};

// inherit functions if any
Cat.prototype = new Animal;

var y = new Cat(1,2,3....);
```

Thanks in advance!
j

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How's this?

```
var Cat = Function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k , l, m, n){
   Animal.apply(this, arguments);
};

// inherit functions if any
Cat.prototype = new Animal;

var y = new Cat(1,2,3....);
```

Comment: "arguments" is a very powerful variable that is automatically in the scope of any function call... look here for more info: http://www.seifi.org/javascript/javascript-arguments.html

Comment: Yuo wouldn't even need to declare the argument list, (a, b, c and so on), in the Cat function. arguments would still contain the values sent in the new Cat(1,2,3...) call.

Comment: Careful: the `prototype= new Animal` call instantiates an `Animal`, calling the constructor function with all the arguments set to `undefined`. For a simple constructor that just stores its argument this is acceptable, but for anything more complicated it'll break. Background and (lengthy!) discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077

Comment: Also, the Animal.apply bit in it self is not inheritance or making use of prototypes. Animal.apply could be called with any object, also an object that does not inherit from Animal.

Comment: @Lars#2: So what? It still answers the question.

Comment: @Lars, I thought only functions/methods can be inherited using prototypes. How would I do the same with prototypes, so I wouldn't need to redefine the argument list for the constructor function cat? Thanks!

Comment: @SLaks, yes it solves the problem, so good suggestion. But on a theoretical level, it is not an inherited constructor, which was also a part of the question. But I'm all for your solution, in practice.

Comment: @John Not only functions/methods can be inherited, other members also gets inherited, like if you would have Animal.prototype.someValue = 1; in your example, cats would also inherit the someValue member. I don't know about constructors though. Seems hard to inherit the constructor as such, since it is the function you use to define the sub class, like Cat. Maybe someone else knows.

Answer (score 1):

It quickly becomes tedious to remember the order and meaning of long lists of parameters like this.

You can add some flexibility if you pass the properties of a new Animal as an object-
and it is not so hard to remember as a long list of argument indexes.

```
function Animal(features){
 for(var p in features){
  this[p]= features[p];
 }
};

You can give every cat some basic cat features automatically, 
and add specifics when you make a new cat.

function Cat(features){
 for(var p in features){
  this[p]= features[p];
 }
}
Cat.prototype= new Animal({legs: 4, eats: 'meat', type: 'mammal', whiskers: true});
Cat.prototype.constructor=Cat;

var Tiger= new Cat({tail: true, hunter: true});
Tiger begins with these properties:

tail: true
hunter: true
legs: 4
eats: meat
type: mammal
whiskers: true
```