# JavaScript inheritance with constructors that have parameters

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

I am new to JavaScript and trying to get my head around inheritance when I have a constructor that takes parameters.

Suppose I have a base object called `Base`:

```
function Base(param1, param2) {
   // Constructor for Base that does something with params
}
```

I want another object, for example called `BaseChild` which inherits from Base and then another object called `Child` which inherits from `BaseChild`.

How would I go about creating the constructors for `BaseChild` and `Child` using **basic JavaScript** (i.e. no special plug-ins)?.

---

Note:

I thought you might be able create BaseChild as follows:

`var BaseChild = new Base(param1, param2);`

But I don't have the values for `param1` or `param2` in `BaseChild`, only in `Child`. I hope this makes sense!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a constructor function to inherit from a constructor function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263353/how-to-get-a-constructor-function-to-inherit-from-a-constructor-function-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// define the Base Class
function Base() {
   // your awesome code here
}

// define the BaseChild class
function BaseChild() {
  // Call the parent constructor
  Base.call(this);
}

// define the Child class
function Child() {
  // Call the parent constructor
  BaseChild.call(this);
}


// inherit Base
BaseChild.prototype = new Base();

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Base
BaseChild.prototype.constructor = BaseChild;

// inherit BaseChild
Child.prototype = new BaseChild();

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to BaseChild
Child.prototype.constructor = BaseChild;
```

alternative approach using **Object.create**

```
BaseChild.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Child.prototype = Object.create(BaseChild.prototype);
```