# Setting an instanced class property overwrites the property in all instances

Tags: javascript, class

I have two instances of a class. Setting a property in the first instance will set it for the second instance too. Why? It shouldn't. The property is not a "prototype property".

Check the code below, what happens to Peter Griffin?
Two objects are created and given the name "Peter Griffin" and "Roger Moore" but the alert boxes will say "Peter Moore" and "Roger Moore". What happened to Peter Griffin?

```
var BaseClass = function(){
    this.name = "";
    this.data = {};
    this.data.lastname = "";
}
var ExtendedClass = function(){
    this.setName = function(fname, lname){
        this.name = fname;
        this.data.lastname = lname;
    }
    this.hello = function(){
        alert("Full name: " + this.name + " " + this.data.lastname);
    }
}
ExtendedClass.prototype = new BaseClass();

pilot = new ExtendedClass();
driver = new ExtendedClass();

pilot.setName("Peter", "Griffin");
driver.setName("Roger", "Moore");

pilot.hello();  // Full name: Peter Moore
driver.hello(); // Full name: Roger Moore
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign a new `this.data= {}` in the `ExtendedClass` constructor. So each `ExtendedClass` instance inherits the `data` object from its prototype `BaseClass` instance. This is a single `Object`! Write `lname` to it from one instance and all the instances will see the change.

JavaScript's constructors and prototypes are a confusing mess. You don't usually want to be using an *instance* (constructed with missing arguments) as the basis for a *class*. This is only one of the many errors that will result.

Also, in the `ExtendedClass` constructor writes a new, separate `hello` method to every instance, instead of sharing the same function between instances as you'd normally do with a prototype.

You've probably got confused by some poorly-written JS OOP tutorial code, which is not surprising since most examples out there are pretty terrible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript) for a (long!) discussion of the various more-consistent approaches to OO in JS.