# What is this pattern called in Javascript? does it have a name?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

component.js

```
var component = (function(){

    var self;

    var default_options = {
        array_option : [],
        string_option : "default"
    };

    return {

        other_function: function(args) {

        },
        init: function(options) {
            self = this;

            // merge in user options 
            for (var attr in options) { 
                if (options.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                    self.o[attr] = options[attr];
                }
            }            

            /***
             * Initialize component
             */

            self.other_function(args);
        }
   };

})();
```

then in the html

```
<script src="component.js"></script>
<script>
    // init the component
    component.init({
        array_option : [1,2,3],
    });
</script>
```

The reason I ask is I have seen it by example and thought it made sense, but is their any reading on why this is good practice? is this Object-Oriented Javascript?

if this **IS** OO javascript, does this pattern make prototypal definitions useless?

***Good answer to above question***

[Javascript: Module Pattern vs Constructor/Prototype pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790909/javascript-module-pattern-vs-constructor-prototype-pattern/3791059#3791059)

Comment: So many answers, all different...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Javascript Module Pattern**](http://ajaxian.com/archives/a-javascript-module-pattern) and yes it attempts to mimic OO Programming with [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

Thats OOP in JS. Its standard practice.

Comment: I guess the reason I ask is I don't see any references to the prototypal definitions...

Answer (score 0):

This is called the self-invoking (anonymous) function. component returns an object that has an init method, so you can chain the calls together.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the Module Pattern at the [YUI Blog](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/).