# Which pattern jQuery $.fn.extend or $.extend use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just reading [Javascript: Module Pattern vs Constructor/Prototype pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790909/javascript-module-pattern-vs-constructor-prototype-pattern) and I was curious to know that when we extend our class with $.fn.extend or $.extend which pattern is used, Module Pattern or Constructor/Prototype pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[✓] None of the above.

This is the *“copy all of this object properties to this other one”* pattern: it just copies in *target* the properties of all other objects.