# Constructor with Module pattern

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use module pattern with the following code:

```
(function(elements) {

    elements.Textbox = function() {
        this.properties = elements.defaultProperties.textboxProperties;
    }

    elements.Textbox.prototype = {
        setSize: function(size) {
            this.properties.size = size;
        },

        getProperties: function() {
            return this.properties;
        },
        getSize: function() {
            return this.properties.size;
        }
    }
}(app.elements || {}));
```

And trying to create and modify objects like so

```
var textbox1 = new app.elements.Textbox();
var textbox2 = new app.elements.Textbox();
textbox2.setSize({
    width: 300,
    height: 100
});
```

But this causes both textboxes to endup with same height and width. I'm new to using Module pattern with Constructor. If I take out Textbox, and then do

```
var textbox1 = new Textbox();
var textbox2 = new Textbox();
textbox2.setSize({
    width: 300,
    height: 100
});
```

This works fine. I'm somewhat misunderstood about this, so thanks in advance for help and clarification.

Edit: I've looked at many SO questions, including: [Javascript: Module Pattern vs Constructor/Prototype pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790909/javascript-module-pattern-vs-constructor-prototype-pattern)
and they've all been very helpful.

Comment: This is because all `texbox.properties` refer to the same object `elements.defaultProperties.textboxProperties`. You have to clone it before assigning e.g. `this.properties = Object.assign({}, defaults...)`

Comment: Yup, works. Thanks. Would you have any other comments on that much piece of code, code-cleanliness, maybe it can be better written, etc.? Thank you!

Comment: `|| {}` should probably be either dropped or changed into `|| (app.elements = {})`

Comment: Please see the link for the waring for deep-copy.  I ended up using JSON.stringify/parse, which works for my case, though it has problems with Date getting converted to String, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

And thanks Bergi.