# javascript inheritnace problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, inheritance

I have two objects, and one inherites from the other.
the parent object sends an ajax request to send some contact email.

if i use the child to send the request, all data is empty ... why is that?
the ajax request is sent (to the right url as well) but the data object is empty.

```
var contact_A = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.url = '/xxx/xxx/xxx';

    this.constructor = function(){ 

        this.dialog = $('.contact_box');

        this.sender = this.dialog.find('input[name=sender]');
        this.name = this.dialog.find('input[name=name]');
        this.content = this.dialog.find('textarea[name=content]');

        ...
    }

    this.init = function(){
       ...
       this.dialog.find('.button_blue').bind('click', function(){
           var data = self.process_form();
          if(data != false) self.send(data);
        });
        ...
    }

    this.process_form = function(){

        this.validator =  new validator('contact_box', true);
        if(this.validator.validate(true)) {

            var data = {
                sender: this.sender.val(),
                name: this.name.val(),
                content: this.content.val()
            }

            return data;
        } else return false;
    }

    this.send = function(data){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: self.url,
            data: data,
            success: function(msg){
                //if not successful
                self.successful(msg);
            },
            async: true
        });

        this.close();
    }

    ...

    this.constructor();
    this.init();
}
```

and this is the inheriting object:

```
var conteact_B = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.constructor();
    this.init();    
}
conteact_B.prototype = new contact_A;
conteact_B.prototype.url = '/yyy/yyy/yyy';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the prototype style of object with the per-instance-members-with-this-closure style of object. This doesn't work well.

The problem is:

```
var contact_A = function(){
    var self = this;
    ... do stuff with self ...
};

conteact_B.prototype = new contact_A;
```

Now the value of `self` will always be what `this` was when the `new contact_A` was constructed. That is: `self` will always be the prototype object, and never the `contact_B` instance.

So whenever `self` is used, it'll be running against the prototype object and not the instance; it won't see any of the member properties assigned in the `constructor`.

To avoid confusion, pick one out of prototypes or this-closure objects. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript) for some background.

Comment: very great link! i now create an instance of contact_A in contact_B function and then change the url. this works good for me.