# Setting a model value from an out of scope function

Tags: function, backbone.js, nested

So I already know a way around this, but I'm curious if there is a better way to handle this call. I should further mention that I'm using Backbone. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
loadKey: function() {
    $.ajax({
        // some settings
        success: function(data) {
            this.set('key', data.key);
        }
    });
}
```

Now obviously this example won't work, because the nested success function is out of the scope of the models this. Here is how I'm currently handling this:

```
loadKey: function() {
    self = this;
    $.ajax({
        // some settings
        success: function(data) {
            self.set('key', data.key);
        }
    });
}
```

So back to my question. Is this a perfectly acceptable way to handle this? Or is there another way to do this that's considered better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use bind from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to bind *this* context when exec the func.

```
loadKey: function() {
    $.ajax({
        // some settings
        success: _.bind(function(data) {
            this.set('key', data.key);
        }, this)
    });
}
```

**Updated**
More discussions on the topics of that=this or self=this:

- [Understanding Bind and bindAll in Backbone.js](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html)
- [Is var self = this; a bad pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371333/is-var-self-this-a-bad-pattern)
- [Getting Out of Binding Situations in JavaScript](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations)

Comment: Is there any reason for doing is this particular way over setting a variable to this? Like my example of setting this to the variable self.

Comment: I use _.bind but you should read through the discussions and make your own call.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful information. I didn't find those discussions in my searching.