# How can I use a method from inherited class

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the inheritance chain `Vehicle -> Motorized -> Car` implemented:

```
function Vehicle()
{
    var m_name;

    this.setName = function(pName) {
        m_name = pName;
    };

    this.getName = function() {
        return m_name;
    };
}

function Motorized()
{
    var m_started = false;

    this.start = function() {
        m_started = true;
        console.log(getName() + " started");
    };
}

function Car()
{ }

//set up the inheritance chain
Motorized.prototype = new Vehicle();
Car.prototype = new Motorized();

// use
var lCar = new Car;
lCar.setName("Focus");
console.log(lCar.getName()); // Focus
lCar.start(); // ReferenceError: getName is not defined
```

When I invoke `lCar.start()` (defined in function Motorized), I get an **ReferenceError: getName is not defined**. How can I use the inherted method `getName()` in my subclass `Motorized`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Javascript doesn't know where to look for your `getName()` method. You can clarify the syntax declaring a `self` variable that always points to the right object, like this:

```
function Vehicle()
{
    var self = this; // Vehicle
    var m_name;

    this.setName = function(pName) {
        self.m_name = pName;
    };

    this.getName = function() {
        return self.m_name;
    };
}

function Motorized()
{
    var self = this; // Motorized
    var m_started = false;

    this.start = function() {
        /*
         `self` is Motorized, with proto Vehicle, so
         has a getName() method.
         `this` instead is the object where you call
         start() from, i.e. Car, in the example down below.
         */
        self.m_started = true;
        console.log(self.getName() + " started");
    };
}

function Car()
{ }

//set up the inheritance chain
Motorized.prototype = new Vehicle();
Car.prototype = new Motorized();

// use
var lCar = new Car;
lCar.setName("Focus");
console.log(lCar.getName()); // Focus
lCar.start(); // Focus started
```

Note that in this case, using the keyword `this` instead of `self` throughout the code would have worked as well, but you definitely cannot omit it before `getName()`. Also, if you are planning to add more code later on, such as event handlers in jQuery, having a clear reference to the class you're coding in can be useful, as `this` can become easily ambiguous, at least from the human point of view.

Anyway, whether using `self` is a bad coding pattern or not is the topic of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371333/is-var-self-this-a-bad-pattern); the point in your example is that you need to call `self.getName()` or `this.getName()`.

Comment: I did not consider to use the function invocation pattern here. Thank you.

Comment: Yes also the `()` were missing but it would have raised exception as well. The method `getName()` is present in `Motorized` and `Car` but the keyword `this` could be tricky, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword), so this can help with debugging issues.