# var that = this in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Sometimes, I come across a piece of javascript code like this:

```
function someFunc() {
    var that = this;
    // do something with that
}
```

Why do people do this when you can just use 'this'?

Comment: Becuase `this` isn't always what you [expect it to be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: In case ```this``` gets redefined later. By storing the original reference in a variable you still have access to the original scope's ```this``, even within other inner scopes

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371333/is-var-self-this-a-bad-pattern

Comment: The answer to this question could be like an Abbott and Costello routine.

Comment: `function someFunc() {
        var that = this;
        var someOther = function(){
            that.theyCame(); // ?
        };
    }`

Comment: @dan1111 No, `that` question, not this.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example:

```
function someFunc() {
  var that = this;
  $('.test').on('click', function() {
    //in this scope the this will be different and if you'd like to use the this of someFunc then you need to assign another variable
  })
}
```