# Inheritance using prototype / "new"

Tags: javascript, oop

Hi I'm new in Javascript OO and want to know more about about inheritance. Hope you can provide some advice!

I see this great post:
[How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077)

which talks about how a class is inherited as I see in other websites, ex.:

```
function man(x) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = 2;
}
man.prototype.name = "man";
man.prototype.two = function() {
    this.y = "two";
}
function shawn() {
    man.apply(this, arguments);
};
shawn.prototype = new man;
```

The above post claims that in order not to call "man"'s constructor while inheriting, one can use a helper like this instead:

```
function subclassOf(base) {
    _subclassOf.prototype= base.prototype;
    return new _subclassOf();
}
function _subclassOf() {};
shawn.prototype = subclassOf(man);
```

While I understand its intention, I don't see why we can't call

```
shawn.prototype = man.prototype;
```

I see it works exactly the same. Or is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, examples are better than words in my humble opinion. All below examples are using your code, with some additions.

The first example will prove that using `shawn.prototype = new man;` you're calling the constructor twice

```js
function man(h, w) {
    SendMessage("man is created with height " + h + " and weight " + w);
    this.height = h;
    this.weight = w;
}
man.prototype.name = "man";
man.prototype.double = function() {
    this.height *= 2;
    this.weigth *= 2;
}
function shawn() {
    man.apply(this, arguments);
};

function SendMessage(msg) {
    document.getElementById("Console").innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
}

window.onload = function() {
    shawn.prototype = new man;
    
    var p = new shawn(180, 90);
    SendMessage("Shawn height: " + p.height);
}
```

```html
<div id="Console"></div>
```

As you see, the constructor is called twice - once with no arguments then with the actual arguments you give it.

The second example just proves that using the `subclassOf` solve that "double calling" issue.

```js
function man(h, w) {
    SendMessage("man is created with height " + h + " and weight " + w);
    this.height = h;
    this.weight = w;
}
man.prototype.name = "man";
man.prototype.double = function() {
    this.height *= 2;
    this.weigth *= 2;
}
function shawn() {
    man.apply(this, arguments);
};

function subclassOf(base) {
    _subclassOf.prototype= base.prototype;
    return new _subclassOf();
}

function _subclassOf() {};

function SendMessage(msg) {
    document.getElementById("Console").innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
}

window.onload = function() {
    shawn.prototype = subclassOf(man);
    
    var p = new shawn(180, 90);
    SendMessage("Shawn height: " + p.height);
}
```

```html
<div id="Console"></div>
```

The third example shows what's wrong with your idea of `shawn.prototype = man.prototype` and I'll explain. `shawn` inherits from `man` so I've added new method that should affect only `shawn`, called `marriage` (that of course cause him to gain some weight ;)) - that method should **not** affect the base class `man` as it's not inheriting from `shawn`, inheritance is one way only. But.... as you see in the example, ordinary `man` can also get married - big problem.

```js
function man(h, w) {
    SendMessage("man is created with height " + h + " and weight " + w);
    this.height = h;
    this.weight = w;
}
man.prototype.name = "man";
man.prototype.double = function() {
    this.height *= 2;
    this.weight *= 2;
}
function shawn() {
    man.apply(this, arguments);
};

function SendMessage(msg) {
    document.getElementById("Console").innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
}

window.onload = function() {
    shawn.prototype = man.prototype;
    
    var p = new shawn(180, 90);
    SendMessage("Shawn height: " + p.height);
    p.double();
    SendMessage("Shawn height: " + p.height);
    
    shawn.prototype.marriage = function() {
       SendMessage("Shawn is getting married, current weight: " + this.weight);
       this.weight += 20;
    };
    
    p.marriage();
    SendMessage("Shawn weight: " + p.weight);
    
    var q = new man(170, 60);
    q.marriage();
    SendMessage("q weight: " + q.weight);
}
```

```html
<div id="Console"></div>
```

Finally, the fourth example shows that using the `subclassOf` everything work fine, as `shawn` inherits `man` properly, and `marriage` is not passed to the base class.

```js
function man(h, w) {
    SendMessage("man is created with height " + h + " and weight " + w);
    this.height = h;
    this.weight = w;
}
man.prototype.name = "man";
man.prototype.double = function() {
    this.height *= 2;
    this.weight *= 2;
}
function shawn() {
    man.apply(this, arguments);
};

function subclassOf(base) {
    _subclassOf.prototype= base.prototype;
    return new _subclassOf();
}
function _subclassOf() {};

function SendMessage(msg) {
    document.getElementById("Console").innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
}

window.onload = function() {
    shawn.prototype = subclassOf(man);
    
    var p = new shawn(180, 90);
    SendMessage("Shawn height: " + p.height);
    p.double();
    SendMessage("Shawn height: " + p.height);
    
    shawn.prototype.marriage = function() {
       SendMessage("Shawn is getting married, current weight: " + this.weight);
       this.weight += 20;
    };
    
    p.marriage();
    SendMessage("Shawn weight: " + p.weight);
    
    var q = new man(170, 60);
    if (q.marriage)
        q.marriage();
    else
        SendMessage("marriage is undefined for man");
    SendMessage("q weight: " + q.weight);
}
```

```html
<div id="Console"></div>
```

Hope this makes some sense! :)

Comment: Wow thanks so much for your answer! The explanation is so well-explained and now everything makes total sense. p.s. I like the marriage function. :)

Comment: @mikkol sure, my pleasure.. hope that my marriage assumption does not apply on you.. ;-)

Comment: I've inlined all your code samples for ease of reference :)

Answer (score 5):

```
shawn.prototype = man.prototype;
```

will share the prototypes, ie modifying one will modify the other.

```
shawn.prototype = new man;
```

will set `shawn.prototype` to a newly created object which inherits from `man.prototype` and thus changes to it won't propagate to `man` instances.

However, using `new` means that the constructor `man()` will be executed, which can have undesired side-effects.

It's better to manually clone the prototype via

```
shawn.prototype = Object.create(man.prototype);
```

if available or a [custom clone function](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/clone.js) (which works the same way as your `subclassOf`)

```
shawn.prototype = clone(man.prototype);
```

otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Shadow's excellent answer, you can think of `shawn.prototype = man.prototype` as meaning `"shawn is the same as man"`, rather than, `"shawn is a man"`

Comment: Yes I didn't realize that they will be "linked" together to be modified at the same time. Thanks!