# ExtJS: Ext.Window Prototypal inherited objects cannot be destroy

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extjs, properties, prototypal-inheritance

[ExtJS 3.4.0]
I have a class with prototypal intheritance to `Ext.Window`, something like this:

```
function Cls_MyWindow() {

    .....

    var SaveButton = new Ext.Button({...});
    var CancelButton= new Ext.Button({...});

    .....

    Cls_MyWindow.prototype.width = Ext.getBody().getWidth() - 800;
    Cls_MyWindow.prototype.height = Ext.getBody().getHeight() - 350;
    Cls_MyWindow.prototype.plain = true;
    Cls_MyWindow.prototype.buttons = [SaveButton, CancelButton];

    .....

}

Cls_MyWindow.prototype = new Ext.Window;
Cls_MyWindow.prototype.constructor = Ext.Window;
```

When this window is shown, it can be closed by pressing the `CancelButton` or the built-in "x" button of `Ext.Window`.

When I **close it with `CancelButton`**, `SaveButton` and `CancelButton` **get destroyed** normally.
But, if is **closed by the "x" button**, the buttons **cannot be destroyed**, the loop is taking forever causing my application to crashed.

After some investigation I found, in **ext-all-debug.js**, this:

```
Ext.Panel = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {

    .....

    if(Ext.isArray(this.buttons)){
        while(this.buttons.length) {
            Ext.destroy(this.buttons[0]);
        }
    }

    .....

}
```

which invoke `Ext.destroy`, this:

```
Ext.apply(Ext, function(){

    .....

    destroy : function(){
        Ext.each(arguments, function(arg){
            if(arg){
                if(Ext.isArray(arg)){
                    this.destroy.apply(this, arg);
                }else if(typeof arg.destroy == 'function'){
                    arg.destroy();
                }else if(arg.dom){
                    arg.remove();
                }
            }
        }, this);
    },

    .....

}());
```

What appears to be is that, `this.buttons` -from pressing CancelButton- are Ext.Component thus, it get destroyed normally.
While `this.buttons` -from pressing "x"- are not, which **leads to the questions**.

- Why `this.buttons` are not the same objects when it is destroy via different way?
- What are the solution/options I have, if I want/need to retain the inheritance?

Shedding me some lights is most appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days, I've found an answered from [Inheritance using prototype / “new”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612609/inheritance-using-prototype-new).
The code around my **first code block** at the **bottom part** is where I got it wrong.

```
Cls_MyWindow.prototype = new Ext.Window;
Cls_MyWindow.prototype.constructor = Ext.Window;
```

The "**new**" at "new Ext.Window" operator there is my mistake.

- Why **this.buttons** are not the same objects when it is destroy via different way?

**Answer:**
Because of the new operator, when I created a new instance of `Cls_MyWindow` total of 2 constructors get called: one of the `Cls_MyWindow`, another of `Ext.Window`. Which then cause them to have "their own prototype of **buttons**" where *SaveButton* and *CancelButton* available in `Cls_MyWindow` as `Ext.Button` objects and in `Ext.Window` as a plain *Object*

Closing Cls_MyWindow with CancelButton -> The buttons can be destroyed in Ext.Window.destroy's way. Closing it with "x" -> The buttons cannot be destroyed.

**Solution:** 
I change my code to

```
//Cls_MyWindow.prototype = new Ext.Window; the old one
Cls_MyWindow.prototype = Ext.Window.prototype;
Cls_MyWindow.prototype.constructor = Ext.Window;
```

and everything works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If we stay within Ext 3.4.0 boundaries, not reaching back to the plain javascript then you haven't done inheritance correctly. Inheritance is already implemented in Ext, so you do not need to go down to prototypes, creating constructors as instances of parent classes, and so on.

Let's suppose you want to define `MyWindow` class inheriting from `Ext.Window`:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow',{
    extend:'Ext.Window'
   ,method:function(){/* some stuff */}
   ,closable:false // don't create close box
   ,closeAction:'hide'
   // etc
});
```

To create an instance:

```
var win = Ext.create('MyWindow', {
    width:800
   ,height:600
});
win.show();
```

For more info see [Ext.define](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext-method-define) docs.

Comment: Thanks @Saki, though, it does not directly answered my question. I already know about `Ext.define` but strangely in my project `Ext.define` is **undefined**, and I don't know why. I'm not the one who implemented the ExtJS into projects and I don't have privileges to do it [ that's sucks :( ]. That's why I used prototypal inheritance. If you can **provide me with link** to understanding the plain javascript prototypal inehritance or **explain** or **point me where I've got it wrong** in this, I would accept your answer.