# OOP Programming in Javascript with Node.js

Tags: oop, node.js

I am actually playing with Javascript doing a small game and I would like to implement what I've found on http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html which is something similar to:

```
ZParenizor.method('toString', function () {
    if (this.getValue()) {
        return this.uber('toString');
    }
    return "-0-";
});
```

I can't find any reference the the library used to make such development possible. Any ideas? Otherwise, I'm looking for a good library that will aid my OOP developments.

Thank you

**Edit:**

I am looking for a OOP solution / library for Node.js. Please note that I'm new to Node.js

Comment: Crockford's a good person to reference for JavaScript.  You're already making a good start.

Comment: Just to be a little more specific, I'm playing with Node.js and I do not need a whole library that offers DOM manipulation, effects, ajax, etc...

Comment: Also check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript) for great object construction/inheritance with JS. Cheers!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

#### 2 months later

Maybe you do need a library, ES5 is verbose as hell so I've created [pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd)

#### Original answer

> I am looking for a OOP solution / library for Node.js.

You **don't** need a library. You have **ES5**.

JavaScript does not have classical OOP. It has prototyping OOP.

This means you have only objects. The only thing you can do with objects is extend, manipulate and clone them.

**Manipulate**

```
var o = {};
o.foo = "bar";
```

**Extend**

```
var o = someObject;
Object.defineProperties(o, {
  "foo": { value: "foo" },
  "bar": { value: "bar" }
  "method": { value: function () { } }
}
```

**Clone**

```
var o = someObject;
var p = Object.create(o);
```

**Clone and extend**

```
var o = someObject;
var p = Object.create(o, {
  "foo": { value: "foo" },
  "bar": { value: "bar" }
  "method": { value: function () { } }
}
```

It's important to understand how [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) work.

The cloning operation isn't actually cloning. It's creating a new object from a blueprint. A blueprint is an object. It places the blueprint in the `[[Prototype]]`. The `[[Prototype]]` lives in the `.__proto__` property which I'll use for demonstration.

```
var o = {};
var p = Object.create(o);
p.__proto__ === o; // true
var q =  Object.create(p);
q.__proto__.__proto__ === o;
var r = Object.create(q);
r.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === o;
```

**Disclaimer:** `.__proto__` is deprecated. Don't use it in code. It has it's uses for debugging and sanity checks though.

The main point here is that accessing properties from `o` in `r` it has to walk 3 levels up the prototype chain and this gets expensive. To solve that problem, rather then cloning random objects you should clone specific blueprints (and you should have one blueprint per object).

```
// Parent blueprint
var Parent = (function _Parent() {
  // create blank object
  var self = Object.create({});

  // object logic

  return self;
}());

// factory function
var createParent = function _createParent(foo) {
  // create a object with a Parent prototype
  return Object.create(Parent, {
    foo: { value: foo }
  });
}

var Child = (function _Child() {
  var self = Object.create(Parent);

  // other stuff

  return self;
}());

var createChild = function _createChild(bar) {
  return Object.create(Child, {
    bar: { value: bar }
  })
};
```

Here's a snippet from some code I'm working on that you can use as an example:

```
var Sketchpad = (function _SketchPad() {
    var self = Object.create({});

    var mousemove = function _mousemove(e) {
        this.drawLine(e);
    };

    self._init = function _init() {
        this.$elem.bind({
            "mousemove": mousemove.bind(this),
        });
        this.pens = {};

        $("#clear").bind("click", this.clear.bind(this));
        $("#undo").bind("click", (function _undoPath() {
            this.pen.undo();
        }).bind(this));

        return this;
    };

    self.clear = function() {
        this.paper.clear();    
    };

    return self;    
}());

createSketch = function _createSketchPad(id, w, h) {
    var paper = Raphael(id, w, h);
    var pen = createPen(paper);
    var o = Object.create(Sketchpad, {
        paper: { value: paper },
        $elem: { value: $("#" + id) },
        pen: { 
            get: function() { return pen; },
            set: function(v) { pen = v; }
        }
    });

    return o._init();
};
```

Comment: this is why I joined Stack Overflow. +1

Answer (score 8):

MooTools is one of the best libraries in terms of OOP Javascript.

You can create classes, interfaces, use inheritance, etc.

Documentation
http://mootools.net/docs/core

Tutorial - MooTools OOP
http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/MooTools-Basic-Creating-Classes-MooTools-P919.html

Comment: I like the tutorial link alot. I'm indeed looking for something similar to Mootools for the OOP aspect. In fact I'm playing with Node.js and I doubt I need the whole library (Mootools).

Comment: There are client side frameworks. MooTools is useless on the server.

Comment: Harsh that I get a down vote *after* the questions was edited to specify server side js... :(

Comment: Yes, pretty harsh, anyway there is a nodejs version now: https://github.com/vsviridov/mootools-node

Answer (score 5):

You might also be interested in [GNU ease.js](http://www.gnu.org/software/easejs/). If you are not interested in the library itself, its manual goes extensively into the implementation details.

You could also see the author's [paper on Classical OOP in ECMAScript](http://www.gnu.org/software/easejs/manual/Implementation-Details.html#Implementation-Details).

Answer (score 3):

You could try Joose, https://github.com/SamuraiJack/Task-Joose-NodeJS. Although, I'd personally recommend to stick with Javascript's object functionality as provided by ES5.

Answer (score 2):

In the article you referenced, he was simply giving an example of what was possible with inheritance in javascript. He was not using a framework, but showing you how to extend your own classes you have written.

Frameworks for javascript include [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) (mvc), and [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) (oop).

Comment: Oh, I hope he could give a complete example then. It looks so easier to understand the way he (Crockford) "do" it with his examples.

Comment: MooTools is a clientside framework. I avoid using it on the server. Backbone is a great server side MVC wrapper.

Comment: when this comment was posted, the Cybrix was not clear he wanted it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

[extjs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext) has support for OOP with **Ext.define** and **Ext.extend** (and **Ext.ns**).  See [this example](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system) on Sencha.com

Ext.extend is the older method, but is still sometimes useful.  You would do something like this:

```
Ext.ns('myApp.myPackage');  // create a namespace 
(function() { // this adds it to the namespace

var MyClass = Ext.extend(BaseClass, {
    property: 1,

    constructor: function(config) {
        Ext.apply(this, config);
    },

    method: function(a, b) { 
        this.property = a + b;
    }
});

myApp.myPackage.MyClass = MyClass;

}) ()
```

With Ext.define in Ext 4+ you can do:

```
Ext.define('myApp.myPackage.MyClass', // don't need to define the namespace first
    extend: 'BaseClass' // notice the base class is referenced by a string,
    requires: 'AnotherClass',
    mixins: { mixin : 'MixinPackage' },

    property: 1,

    constructor: function(config) {
        //...
    }

   method: function(a, b) {
        this.property = a + b;
    }
});
```

Note that you can also use traditional [OOP in javascript](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html) with 'new' and function.prototype

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a real strong OOP in Javascript/Node, you can have a look at the full-stack open source framework [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf).

It allows you to use OOP (and so the same classes) on both the server (node) and client (browser) sides.
It also provides a nice dependency injection mechanism (looking as the one of Symfony2 if you come from the PHP community).