# Javascript Accessing Parent Object inside Function

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Car function:

```
var Car = function(vendor, model, year) {
    return {
        vendor: vendor,
        model: model,
        year: year,
        name: (function() {
            return vendor + " " + model + " " + year;
        })()
    };
};
var foo = Car("Toyota","Corola",2007);
alert(foo.name);  //alerts "Toyota Corola 2007"
```

This works, but I want the `name` to be able to change according to the `vendor`, `model`, and `year`.

```
taxi.vendor = "Mitsubishi";
alert(taxi.vendor); //still alerts "Toyota Corola 2007"
```

How can I instead make it alert `Mitsubishi Corola 2007` according to the change of the `vendor` property?

EDIT: **And the catch** -- `name` must remain a property that does not need to be called as a function.

Comment: I'm in trouble, I didn't check the prior posts!

[Prior Cool Discussion][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349121/choosing-an-oop-pattern-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With recent versions of WebKit (Safari, Chrome) or Firefox, you can [define getter and setter functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters):

```
var o = {a: 7, get b() {return this.a + 1;}, set c(x) {this.a = x / 2}};
o.b // result is 8
o.a = 10
o.b // result is 11
```

Then you would do this:

```
var Car = function(vendor, model, year) {
    return {
        vendor: vendor,
        model: model,
        year: year,
        get name() { return this.vendor + " " + this.model + " " + this.year; }
    };
};
```

And get the result that you want.

I don't know if IE or Opera support this or which versions. If you need to support anything other than recent Safari, Chrome, or Firefox browsers then you're better off using a function to access the name instead of leaving it as a property:

```
var Car = function(vendor, model, year) {
    return {
        vendor: vendor,
        model: model,
        year: year,
        name: function() { return this.vendor + " " + this.model + " " + this.year; }
    };
};
```

And then:

```
var foo = Car("Toyota","Corola",2007);
alert(foo.name());  //alerts "Toyota Corola 2007"
foo.vendor = "Mitsubishi";
alert(foo.name());  //alerts "Mitsubishi Corola 2007"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
 var Car = function(thevendor, themodel, theyear) {
    this.vendor = thevendor;
    this.model = themodel,
    this.year = theyear,
    this.name = function() {
            return this.vendor + " " + this.model + " " + this.year;
        };
    return this;
};


var foo = new Car("Toyota","Corola",2007);
alert(foo.name());  //alerts "Toyota Corola 2007"

foo.vendor = "Mitubishi";
alert(foo.name());  //alerts "Mistubishi Corola 2007"
```

JSFiddle for this code: http://jsfiddle.net/duncan_m/gZKQD/

Answer (score 2):

When you use `name: (function() {return vendor + " " + model + " " + year;})()`, that means that the `name` property will be set to *the result of executing this function*. This happens when you create a new `Car`. But it sounds like you want this to update dynamically, so consider having `name` be a getter function instead of just a string property:

`name: function() {return vendor + " " + model + " " + year;}`

Then you can do `alert(taxi.name())`, which will dynamically concatenate the vendor, model, and year strings.

Comment: Is it possible without making `name` a function?

Comment: If you want to do it without making `name` a function, you would have to make setter functions (e.g. `setVendor`, `setModel`, and `setYear`) so that each time something changes you could recreate the `name`. You can also use [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters) as another commenter mentioned.