# Override Methods with Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm using this clone method for prototypal inheritance from [Pro JavaScript Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059908X) which is basically the same as [Crockford's object() function](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html). (The only difference is that Crockford adds invoke parens, but since F is empty I'm not sure that it matters. I don't think that the issue.)

```
clone = function(object) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = object;
    return new F;
};
```

So, applying this, I'm looking to make two objects, one which inherits methods from the other. One is for viewport dimensions and one is for device dimensions. But both use similar math comparisons so I think it makes sense to have one inherit the other. ([More info about the actual methods is here](http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/).)

```
var Viewport = {
    inORout: function (curr, min, max) {
        // !@return boolean true if curr equals min or max, or is in between.
        min = min || 0; // Default min.
        return !max ? ( curr >= min ) : ( curr >= min && curr <= max );
    }
  , width: function() {
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
    }
  , height: function() { 
        return document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
    }
  , inWidthRange: function (min, max) {
        return this.inORout(this.width(), min, max);
    }
  , inHeightRange: function (min, max) {
        return this.inORout(this.height(), min, max);
    }
};

// I want to use prototypal inheritance to make Device inherit the
// inORout/inWidthRange/inHeightRange methods from Viewport but 
// override the width() and height() methods:
var Device = clone(Viewport);
Device.width = function() {
    return window.screen.width; 
};
Device.height = function() {
    return window.screen.height; 
};
```

But the problem is that I get errors like this:

```
 Object # <Object> has no method 'inORout'
 and 
 Object # <Object> has no method 'width'
 and 
 Object # <Object> has no method 'height'
```

If I change reference to `this.width()` etc. in Viewport to `Viewport.width()` etc. the errors go away but then I think that the inheritance doesn't work. The errors happen when I use methods from either object. What am I missing? Is there a better pattern for this? How can I make this work?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/VNAQa/5/)

Comment: @Raynos @André Alçada Padez I figured it out. The problem was that I was using the methods in a way that changed the context of `this`. The methods weren't defined on *that* `this`.

Answer (score 1):

with prototype you have to do things a little different:

```
var Viewport = {};
Viewport.prototype.inOrOut = function(){...};
Viewport.prototype.width= function(){...};
Viewport.prototype.height = function(){...};
```

this way, you will be able to inherit properly...

Comment: Isn't that classical inheritance? I tried it anyway and it gives the error `Cannot set property 'inORout' of undefined`. The `clone()` method should handle that. I believe it's equivalent to `Object.create` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create added in JavaScript 1.8.5

Comment: function F() {}   -> aren't you missing an = (equal sign) there?

Comment: Inside a function `function F() {}` is equivalent to `var F = function() {};`

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez `function F() {}` is just a local function declaration. Which work the exact same as global function declarations, except they are local.

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but i tried yours and it works http://jsfiddle.net/andrepadez/c7GYy/