# Use $.extend() for prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Maybe this is a crazy question, but something like:

```
var MyPrototypeObject {
    prop: 0;
};    
var ob1 = Object.create(MyPrototypeObject);
var ob2 = { 
    meth: function() { 
        this.prop = 5; // update prop 
        return this.prop;
    }
};
```

where [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) clones the prototype and [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is used to add additional methods to `ob1`, where `this.prop` points back to the prototype? What's the best way to add new methods?

```
$.extend(ob1, ob2);
```

Related: [Override Methods with Prototypal Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022519/override-methods-with-prototypal-inheritance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pd-style](https://gist.github.com/1441105) is similar and recommends

```
var SomeProto = {
    prop: 0;
};    

var ob1 = extend(Object.create(SomeProto), { 
    meth: function meth() { 
        return (this.prop = 5); // update prop 
    }
});
```

This is an effective way of handling OO in JavaScript. Note that `$.extend` is a shit implementation for doing this because it has an `isPlainObject` check which returns `false` for objects that have prototypes

Comment: Hell yea! =] In that setup can you use `this` in `SomeProto`? I got it to work except when I tried to use `this` in used in the methods of `SomeProto`. Shouldn't I be able to do that?

Comment: @ryanve of course. Note that `this !== SomeProto` inside `SomeProto` it's whatever `this` context you pass in when you invoke the method.

Comment: Great yea, exactly, that's what I want. I must have a mistake somewhere else.