# What is Object programming in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express, javascript-objects

Strictly speaking what is the **OBJECT PROGRAMMING** *part* of node.js ? is it :

- express.js
- Javascript
- node.js itself
- some programming component ?

**In theory how can we best define the object programming part of node.js ?**

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6339819/334813

Comment: This is a broad, subjective question. 'Strictly speaking' suggests you're working with a formal definition (or someone's idea of one). Is this an exam question?

Comment: Node is just a JavaScript implementation. Express is a framework. The question basically answers itself, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your question or someone else's? It sounds like the wrong question.

Node.js is just another implementation (runtime environment) of JavaScript that you can run outside of the browser.

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) itself is an **object**-oriented programming language

When you're writing JavaScript that gets executed using the node process, I suppose the "objects" would be the objects you've defined and used in your code.

- Express.js is just a program written in JavaScript. I certainly would not call that an "object" in any sort of programming context.
- JavaScript is a language; not an object.
- Node.js is an *implementation* of JavaScript, meaning it can interpret/execute a JavaScript file. Node.js is not an object.
- "Some component" is also probably not an object in the way you're understanding.